# Beamer navigation circles without subsections?

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames

I have been using the `Frankfurt` theme in Beamer recently. It includes navigational section titles at the top of the slide and when subsections are included, it adds circles below section titles. Each circle represents a slide. The circle representing the active slide is filled and the circles representing the active subsection are shown in bold.

My question is:

- Is it possible to include navigational circles in a Beamer presentation to represent each slide while having sections, but not subsections?

My motivation:

- I think this would be useful to highlight to readers the number of slides per section and it would also be a useful navigational tool.

Comment: The Singapore theme (and perhaps others) have a `compress` option which does what you want.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't need to declare a subsection, raising it's counter by `\setcounter{subsection}{1}` or `\stepcounter{subsection}` would be sufficient.

But as the section counter resets the subsection counter, I would do it in the preamble together with removing it from the reset:

```
\usepackage{remreset}% tiny package containing just the \@removefromreset command
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
```

This way that counter will stay at the value 1 and the circles are shown without any `\subsection`.

A minimal working example demonstrating the solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\frame{one}
\frame{two}
\frame{three}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you uncomment the command `\setcounter{subsection}{1}` and compile twice, you could see the original problem of missing circles.

Answer (score 11):

Since Beamer by default only displays dots for subsections, I found that it was easiest to put `\AtBeginSection[]{\subsection{}}` in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\AtBeginSection[]{\subsection{}}
```

I found this to work better than other answers that messed with counters and left me with output like this:

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm for me with theme Darmstadt.

Comment: this is the easiest fix suggested. I only added the \AtBeginSection line also (no miniframes) +upvoted

Comment: A stunning solution, especially when you have a Title page and the Outline page. Whilst the accepted solution also counts these two pages in the navigation dots, this solution does not.

Answer (score 8):

Really? I thought the circles would always be shown, even without declared subsections. That's what the example in the documentation appears to show, and it's the way I seem to remember that theme behaving when I used it in the past. (It was a while ago, perhaps I'm misremembering, and my LaTeX is broken so I can't test)

Anyway, as a quick fix, I suppose you could just declare one nameless subsection per section.

```
\section{Axxqzropy}
\subsection{}
```

Maybe define a command for it,

```
\newcommand*{\ssection}[1]{\section{#1}\subsection{}}
```

although this is admittedly a hack, not an ideal solution.

Comment: thanks, the subsection hack worked in terms of showing the circles. But it also had the side effect of removing the PDF sidebar navigation.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution that doesn't mess around with the subsection numbering, but just patches beamer so that "subsections numbered 0" show their slide entries. Frames immediately below `\section`s without `\subsection`s get treated as subsection 0 and highlighted in a different group to any actual later `\subsection`s. Therefore, subsections are not needed to get frames to show corresponding the navigation circles, but it doesn't prevent (or rather, obfuscate) subsection use.

Beamer's `\slideentry` has a test that checks if the current subsection number exceeds zero before it agrees to show the navigation circle; I have just patched that test by replacing it with something that's always true (but still in the `if` conditional form so it shouldn't break anything).

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\ifnum#2>0}{\ifnum2>0}{}{\@error{unable to patch}}% replace the subsection number test with a test that always returns true
\makeatother
```

Note that it may also be necessary to do the same for `\fakeslideentry` (if using multiple parts?). If not using the `compress` option, it may also be necessary to `\advance\beamer@ypos by1\relax` before the `\fi` in the `\ifbeamer@compress` `else` clause. However, the above alone "works" in the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\ifnum#2>0}{\ifnum2>0}{}{\@error{unable to patch}}% replace the subsection number test with a test that always returns true
\makeatother

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

% to illustrate the subsection numbering
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]

\begin{document}
\frame{\tableofcontents}
\section{Test I}
\frame{one}
\frame{two}
\subsection{A}
\frame{three}
\frame{four}
\subsection{B}
\frame{five}
\section{Test II}
\frame{six}
\subsection{C}
\frame{seven}
\section{Test III}
\frame{eight}
\end{document}
```

(I realise that this may no longer be useful to the original poster, but it might help someone. This is what I wanted to do but found only this question and its original answers.)

Comment: See also issue 218 in the `beamer` issue tracker: [miniframes and smoothbars don't show progress markers without subsections](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/218/miniframes-and-smoothbars-dont-show)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and cyberSingularity's answer worked for me. I filled it out so that it does work with the `compact` option, and also patched `\fakeslideentry`. The trickery with `\ifhadanonsubsecn` means that your various sections can be different: some can have subsections, some can lack them, and some can have some slides before their first subsection. Anyway maybe this will be useful to someone.

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter

\pretocmd\sectionentry{%
  \let\ifhadanonsubsecn\@secondoftwo
}{}{\@error{unable to patch \string\sectionentry}{}}

\patchcmd\slideentry{%
  \ifnum#2>0%
}{%
  \ifnum2>0%
}{}{\@error{unable to patch \string\slideentry}{}}

\patchcmd\slideentry{%
  \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
  \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
}{%
  \ifnum#2=0\relax
  \let\ifhadanonsubsecn\@firstoftwo
  \fi
  \beamer@xpos=#3\relax
  \beamer@ypos=#2\relax
  \ifhadanonsubsecn{%
    \advance \beamer@ypos by1\relax
  }{}%
}{}{\@error{unable to patch \string#1}}%

\patchcmd\fakeslideentry{%
  \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
  \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
}{%
  \ifnum#2=0\relax
  \let\ifhadanonsubsecn\@firstoftwo
  \fi
  \beamer@xpos=#3\relax
  \beamer@ypos=#2\relax
  \ifhadanonsubsecn{%
    \advance \beamer@ypos by1\relax
  }{}%
}{}{\PackageError{patchbeamernav}{unable to patch \string#1}}%

\@addtoreset{subsectionslide}{section}
\makeatother
```

(Without the `\@addtoreset` at the end, when the first slide in a section is not in a subsection, it might get counted as, say, slide #3, and that would have the effect of moving the circle corresponding to that slide over to the right; gross.)