# Getting "dots" to show up in Beamer headers

Tags: beamer, header-footer, mini-frames

I'm writing a presentation in Beamer using the Frankfurt theme. I like the dots that appear in the header denoting various slides (as in [this sample](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/all/beamer-beaver-Frankfurt-1.png)), but I can't seem to get them to show up. Compiling various Frankfurt-based presentations found on the Internet is also no help.

My basic slide setup is

```
\begin{frame}{Here's the title}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item some points...
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

How can I get the nice circles in the header of the slides?

Answer (score 12):

Pardon the question, [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/beamer-navigation-circles-without-subsections) was found in *overflow's "related" section. Long story short: Frankfurt requires subsections in order to render the little circles; updating the subsection counter by `\setcounter{subsection}{1}` after each new section heading is sufficient for this (if you're not interested in subsections).

Comment: -1 for answering your own question after six minutes; +2 for the "counter" trick. BTW, you should use `\stepcounter{subsection}` to get the correct color (grey instead of white) for empty circles.

Comment: and what happens to the table of contents?

Comment: @lockstep: self-answering is explicitly encouraged. As is searching for related questions before posting.

Comment: @Caramdir: I'm not against self-answering (I've done it myself frequently), but rather against waiting less than, say, 30 minutes before providing an answer to one's one question.

Comment: @lockstep: I'd say one should write an answer when one has it. That save the time of everyone else.

Comment: @Caramdir: It certainly didn't save my time in this case. ;-) (At least I learned something new about `beamer`.) BTW, I've added the {header-footer} tag to the "related question" so that searching may yield better results from now on.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\begin{frame}{foo}
bar
\end{frame}
\subsection{foobar}
\begin{frame}{baz}
baz
\end{frame}
\subsection{foobarbaz}
\begin{frame}{baz}
baz
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Actually, using `\stepcounter{subsection}` after every `\section{...}` gives better results than using `\setcounter{subsection}{1}`. For my document, the latter misplaced the dots.