# Mini frame navigation not drawn correctly

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames

I want to use a trick I found in the question [Beamer navigation circles without subsections?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/beamer-navigation-circles-without-subsections) to suppress multiple lines of "frame dots" for each subsection in `beamer`'s mini frame navigation. Instead, I want to have a line of frame dots for each section. This fails with the outer theme `miniframe`, but not with the outer theme `smoothbars`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetheme{M21}
\title
{Long Title}  
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Christoph}
\date{}
\subject{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}    
\section[One]{Sec 1}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Some Frame}
  \framesubtitle{its subtitle}
  and some bla bla
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{More...}
  \framesubtitle{more subtitle}
  and some bla bla
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Last Frame in Section}
  and some bla bla
\end{frame}

\section{Sec 2}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Some Frame}
  \framesubtitle{its subtitle}
  and some bla bla
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{More...}
  \framesubtitle{more subtitle}
  and some bla bla
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Last Frame in Section}
  and some bla bla
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My theme file `beamerthemeM21.sty` has the following content:

```
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother

\mode<presentation>
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\mode<all>
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
%\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

As it is now, the MWE should show correct dots, like so:

```
One        Sec 2
Ooo        ooo
```

If you comment `smoothbars` and activate `miniframes`, the line of dots is shifted to the right, and the shift amount increases for each section:

```
One        Sec 2
  Ooo          ooo
```

How can I avoid that? Where did I mess it up?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the outer theme `smoothbars` uses the beamer option [`compress`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsubsection.8.2.3) in order to get the mini frames into one single line, while `miniframes` doesn't do that by default. So in order to remove the spurious space, you need to activate this compression, which can be done by saying

```
\beamer@compresstrue
```

in `beamerthemeM21.sty` (enclosed in `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`, of course).

BTW: You don't need to use `\setcounter{subsection}{1}` in each section as in your MWE, doing this once (e. g. in your theme file) is enough.

So the corrected `beamerthemeM21.sty` looks like this:

```
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\beamer@compresstrue
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\mode<presentation>
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\mode<all>
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```