# Hide some slides from the miniframes navigation in beamer

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I am using the Dresden theme on a presentation with a few sections, each with a couple of subsections.

For each slide in a subsection, a circle appears in the navigation bar.
I'm trying to hide this circle for some slides (images or continuations where using animations doesn't make sense), to keep the navbar organized.

I have tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45038/6239) answer, however, that only works when the compress theme option is enabled.
Without compress enabled, there is still space for the circle, but the circle itself is not drawn.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just combine [the idea you mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37127/how-to-remove-some-pages-from-the-navigation-bullets-in-beamer/45038#45038) with [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31483/mini-frame-navigation-not-drawn-correctly).

Eventually you need:

```
    \makeatletter
    \let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry
    \def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
      \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
      {%else
        % removed \addtocontents commands
        \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
      }
    }
    \newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
    \newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
    \beamer@compresstrue
    \makeatother
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it possible to still highlight the last dot in order to fake overlays with multiple frames?

Comment: @tobiasBora, have you found a solution to keep the last dot highlighted? I need the same functionality.

Comment: Someone found a solution to highlight the last dot when miniframes are off?