# Remove dots from Beamer miniframes style

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

Can anybody help me remove the subsection dots from the navigation bar in Beamer miniframes outer theme?

Edit:
This is the preamble what worked:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{palatino}

\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}

\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=DeepSkyBlue4} 
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=black} 

\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@writeslidentry{\clearpage\beamer@notesactions}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\(}{\begin{columns}}
\renewcommand{\)}{\end{columns}}
\newcommand{\<}[1]{\begin{column}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\>}{\end{column}}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: Don't use the `miniframes` theme if you don't like the dots.

Comment: Which theme could I use then, to get the subsection frames but not the dots? I tried editing the .sty file but couldn't find my way around really.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be not the best way but I found it here [Hide some slides from the miniframes navigation in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234269/hide-some-slides-from-the-miniframes-navigation-in-beamer)
and I think that I can use it in your needs like:

```
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@writeslidentry{\clearpage\beamer@notesactions}
\makeatother
```

Add it in your preamble and check if it is ok for what you want

Edited to make it simpler...