# How not to show subsection navigation bullets in the metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, sectioning, beamer-metropolis

I have two questions

1. I am using the `metropolis` theme with a section indicator as suggested by samcarter ([Adding section indicator to Metropolis theme?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364904/adding-section-indicator-to-metropolis-theme)). But I don't want to show subsection bullet dots as I have many subsections and each dot for each frame of the subsections will overflow. So I want to show only section indicators.
2. Also I want to put the section indicator at the bottom of frame instead of at the top.

Comment: check the solution from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375839/remove-dots-from-beamer-miniframes-style/375843#375843

Comment: Can you please edit your question to give a minimal document that shows what the issue is.

Comment: @koleygr That solution seems to remove all the dots, not the subsection dots only.

Comment: @AlanMunn I don't exactly remember...just came in my mind with the question... The question there is about subsections too... but without a MWE I can not check it or change it (as you mentioned too)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}{}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current section}{}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip-2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=normal text.bg, bg=structure.fg}

\begin{document}

\section{section 1}
\subsection{section name}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{blub}
    abc
\end{frame} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{blub}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{section 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{blub}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{section 3}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{blub}
    abc
\end{frame}     

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Second solution including framenumbers**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}{}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current section}{}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth, sep=3ex]{footline}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamertemplate*{frame footer}
    \hfill%
    \usebeamertemplate*{frame numbering}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip-2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=normal text.bg, bg=structure.fg}

\begin{document}

\section{section 1}
\subsection{section name}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{blub}
    abc
\end{frame} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{blub}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{section 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{blub}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{section 3}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{blub}
    abc
\end{frame}     

\end{document}
```

Comment: This option of navigation is good but it is covering the slide numbers how to shift slide numbers little up.

Comment: @ShivugpKumar see my edit

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. what do you mean by "see my edit

Comment: @ShivugpKumar Please see the additional second solution in my answer. I hope it solves your framenumber problem

Comment: Thank you very much, how it should be modified to show slide numbers in fraction (like 1/5).

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions; One more question is in section I will writ like this \section[short heading]{long heading}. Long heading is  showing in table of contents, short heading is showing at bottom navigation index and at the beginning of that section, but I want to show the long title at the beginning of each section, how should I do that?

Comment: @ShivugpKumar Comments are not the right place to ask totally unrelated questions.

Comment: sorry I am new to this site.