# Add section without appearance in navigation bar with Beamer v 3.50

Tags: beamer, sectioning, navigation

Currently on my laptop I've Beamer v3.43. When I want to have a section that does not appear on the navigation bar, I use `\section{}` (or `\section*{}`) as mentioned in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66628/latex-beamer-frame-outside-sections).

A student of my has recently installed Beamer and has version 3.50 installed (published in February 2018). For this version of Beamer, the proposed solution fails. The section is still added to the navigation bar with `\section{}`.

Section 10.2 of the [Beamer user guide](http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) v3.50 tells the following about the working of the `\section` command:

> \section<⟨mode specification⟩>[⟨short section name⟩]{⟨section name⟩}
>   Starts a section. No heading is created. By default the ⟨section name⟩ is shown in the table of contents and
>   in the navigation bars; if ⟨short section name⟩ is specified, it will be used in the navigation bars instead; if
>   ⟨short section name⟩ is explicitly empty, it will not appear in the navigation bars. If a ⟨mode specification⟩
>   is given, the command only has an effect for the specified modes.

My guess would be that `\section[]{}` will do the job. Unfortunately, the section is still added to the navigation bar.

Furthermore, the solution in v3.43 `\section*{}` is also no solution anymore according to the user guide:

> \section<⟨mode specification⟩>*{⟨section name⟩}
>   Starts a section without an entry in the table of contents. No heading is created, but the ⟨section name⟩ is
>   shown in the navigation bar.

So how should I solve this problem with the new Beamer version?

A minimal working example is the following one (taken from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66628/latex-beamer-frame-outside-sections))

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Sec1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame1}
\end{frame}

\section{Sec2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame2}
\end{frame}

\section{} % this works for v3.43, not for v3.50
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame3}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

BTW, I'm not testing things on my own laptop as I've not found a satisfying solution to downgrade packages to earlier versions.

Comment: I've logged this as https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/471: I suspect I'll need to trace through to find what is 'wrong' (it's  a bit tricky: Till really did want everything properly in sections!)

Comment: @JosephWright There had been some changes last year to better support frames without subsections. The behaviour was changed with them.

Comment: @samcarter I know :) I think that the old behaviour here was an artefact of a bug, but that does mean we need a way to 'escape' sections entirely: may need a new command (or go down the ConTeX route and have `\begin{section}` ... `\end{section}`!)

Comment: @JosephWright maybe something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45038/36296 would be useful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375843/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Sec1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame1}
\end{frame}

\section{Sec2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame2}
\end{frame}



\section{} % this works for v3.43, not for v3.50

{
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@writeslidentry{\clearpage\beamer@notesactions}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame3}
\end{frame}
}

\section{Sec4}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame4}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This workaround did solve the problem, see https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vDqEv3yGy8BwTMHzcMmO-XDp7R5UuTc9/view?usp=sharing