# Beamer Exclude Slide From Navigation Numbering

Tags: beamer, navigation

My goal is to show different source code versions. For readability, I prefer to have those versions on different frames, but for the organization of the presentation, it should seem like one frame. Changing the page counter can be done by `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}`.

This would be an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{My Code}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
class ClassA {
 public void methodA() {
  new ClassB().methodB1();
 }
}
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{My Code}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
class ClassA {
 public void methodA() {
  new ClassB().methodC1();
 }
}
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Final Remarks}
...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But I could not find a solution for changing the navigation. Setting the counter with `\setcounter{subsection}{1}` did not set the correct counter, since this seems to set the subsection, not the frame number in the subsection. Is there any way of finding a counter, e.g. in a list of all defined counters?

[Hide some slides from the miniframes navigation in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234269/hide-some-slides-from-the-miniframes-navigation-in-beamer) is very similar to the solution, but if I use this, the current navigation circle is not highlighted. Is there a solution where the circle for the current (last) frame stays highlighted, but there is no circle added in the navigation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Messing with the miniframe navigation is tricky, I would not do it unless it is really necessary.

Instead simply use only a single frame and split it in several overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{My Code}

\begin{onlyenv}<1>
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
class ClassA {
 public void methodA() {
  new ClassB().methodB1();
 }
}
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}

\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
class ClassA {
 public void methodA() {
  new ClassB().methodC1();
 }
}
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Final Remarks}
...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the best answer here. I had very hard ties with the \minifrimesoff function described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37127/how-to-remove-some-pages-from-the-navigation-bullets-in-beamer

Comment: Great answer. `\begin{onlyenv}<1> ... \end{onlyenv}` `\begin{onlyenv}<2> ... \eng{onlyenv}` is the trick, and it is applicable for rmarkdown beamer users as well. Is there a way to change the slide title for the `\begin{onlyenv}<2>` part, by the way?

Comment: @MatthewSon Sure, you can have different titles with `\frametitle<1>{foo} \frametitle<2>{bar}`