# Frames with bibliography are not added to the circle progress bar in smoothbars

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies, navigation, mini-frames

I'm working with a `Warsaw` theme and `smoothbars` outtertheme.

I'm adding a bibliography entry at the end of the presentation that is meant to be used for a list of publications. However, these slides are not added to the circle progress bar (does this have a technical name?) from the `smoothbars`.

Checking the [Beamer navigation circles without subsections?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/beamer-navigation-circles-without-subsections) question I thought that adding some subsections will do the trick but that didn't work. It seems that if the frame contains a `\printbibliography` (and I guess any bibliography) then the frame is skipped from the progress bar. Also, I'm not sure if this has something to do with this [bug](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/218).

Check the following example. The first frame appears by adding the subsection. The frames in the second subsection with the subsection in them appear also, with exception of the one with the bibliography on it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{test1,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach,
               Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
\end{filecontents}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}


\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}{test}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{Publications}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}{in nav}
this frame is in navigation bar
\end{frame}

\subsection{References}
\begin{frame}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}{in nav}
this frame is also in navigation bar, but the previous one isn't
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

So, how can I make the slides with a bibliography on them to appear in the `smoothbars`/circle progress bar?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Use `\printbibliography[heading=none]`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel wow... indeed an easy solution. I thought it will require some fancy workaround.

Comment: Do you need an explanation?

Comment: That would be nice, and good for completeness (so I can mark it as an answer). I guess that the `subbibliography` is doing something to the heading and that is avoiding the inclusion since it is a bibliography. Once you remove the heading, then it is not recognized as one any more, and the default behavior triggers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution in a short form: Use

```
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

**Explanation**

*`biblatex`-part*

`biblatex` tests which document class is loaded. The class `beamer` isn't valid option and so the default setting of `abx@classtype` is used. With these settings the option `heading=subbibliography` represents the following definition:

```
\defbibheading{subbibliography}[\refname]{%
  \subsection*{#1}}
```

The definition is done in the file `biblatex.def`. It's important to notice that the starred version of `\subsection` is used.

`beamer`-part

In `beamer` the structuring commands like `\subsection` should be placed outside the environment `frame`. If you put such commands inside `frame` you will get unwanted side effects. In your case the command `\subsection*` removes the entry in the `smoothbar`.

A simple example demonstrates this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection*{Subsection}
\begin{frame}{test}
content...a
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{test}
\subsection*{Subsection b}
content...b
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Based on the explanation above you must remove `\subsection*` which is done by `heading=subbibliography`. The simplest way is the usage of `heading=none` which is defined as:

```
\defbibheading{none}{}
```