# Tick marks on Lyx Beamer Presentation

Tags: beamer, lyx

I'm writing a presentation with Lyx. I don't find how to include this line of balls on top that tell you where you are in the presentation.

This is a [sample lyx file](https://gist.github.com/frashokereti/5863260) with this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have `section`s and `subsection`s in order to have the navigation buttons. Please see the updated [lyx file](https://gist.github.com/5864391.git) that I have uploaded.

---EDITED---

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/265966/4801), an easy way to have the navigation buttons without adding `subsection`s is `\AtBeginSection[]{\subsection{}}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 4):

Which beamer theme do you use? The navigation buttons are theme-dependent. See http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html for the theme list and choose the one with the navigation buttons. For example, add `\usetheme{Frankfurt}` to LaTeX preamble in Document -> Settings.

Comment: I'm using 'Dresden' which according to this link has navigation buttons. But they don't appear in my pdf.

Comment: The navigation bar depends on the `outer` theme, not in the `theme` itself. One can activate the navigation bar for any theme (that doesn't include it by default) by using, for example, `\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}`.