# Allowframebreaks causes beamer miniframes to misbehave

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

The following minimal working example should adequately illustrate the issue I am experiencing with the use of miniframe and framebreaks, namely that frames that break over multiple frames are all highlighted as active at once in the miniframe bullets. I would like only the active frame of the miniframe bullets to be marked active.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

%http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66626/9115
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\ifnum#2>0}{\ifnum2>0}{}{\@error{unable to patch}}% replace the subsection number test with a test that always returns true
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Introduction}
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item Five
\item Six
\item Seven
\item Eight
\item Nine
\item Ten
\item Eleven
\item Twelve
\item Thirteen % Break occurs after this item
\item Fourteen
\item Fifteen
\item Sixteen
\item Seventeen
\item Eighteen
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Both frames of the broken enumeration are marked active]

Comment: Related (2022): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633032

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Note that the original bug as worked around in [this answer to question 2072](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66626) has since been solved upstream in beamer, and hence the workaround now hurts rather than helps. I've removed it from the below.)

Following the programming by permutation anti-pattern, the following seems to work (two extra patches, changing `\c@subsectionslide` which is not unique for broken frames to `\c@framenumber`, which is):

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% use frame numbers instead of subsection slide numbers so that frames broken over slides get separate circles
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\c@subsectionslide}{\c@framenumber}{}{\errmessage{unable to patch \string\slideentry}}
\patchcmd{\beamer@writeslidentry}{\c@subsectionslide}{\c@framenumber}{}{\errmessage{unable to patch \string\beamer@writeslideentry}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Introduction}
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item Five
\item Six
\item Seven
\item Eight
\item Nine
\item Ten
\item Eleven
\item Twelve
\item Thirteen % Break occurs after this item
\item Fourteen
\item Fifteen
\item Sixteen
\item Seventeen
\item Eighteen
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test} Testing \end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}{Another test} Lorem ipsum \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Comment in 2022: I tried this code, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633032. It does not seem to be working anymore.