# Using conditionals to ignore command does not work

Tags: beamer, conditionals, report, patching

I am trying to pdflatex a file but I get the following error:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line [...].
```

The source of the error is a patch I used from here: [Allowframebreaks causes beamer miniframes to misbehave](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132285/allowframebreaks-causes-beamer-miniframes-to-misbehave)

I use a construction with `\if` to load certain packages, depending on which documentclass I use. Normally if something only works with beamer, I put it inside a \iftargetBeamer-\else-\fi-block and at the beginning of the document I just write `\targetReporttrue` if I don’t wont to use it.

My problem now is that LaTeX does not ignore the text if the condition is false.

I have created a minimum “working” example of my problem:

```
\newif\iftargetReport
\newif\iftargetBeamer

\targetReporttrue

\iftargetReport
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, ngerman]{scrreprt}
\else\iftargetBeamer
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, ngerman]{beamer}
\else
\typeout{no valid class defined, enter Ctrl-D (Linux) or Ctrl-Z (Windows)}
\endinput
\fi\fi

\iftargetBeamer
\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox} % <- You can savely uncomment this if using report. This implies LaTeX does ignore this block.
% HERE is the problem!! Comment out next line to "fix" the issue.
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\ifnum#2>0}{\ifnum2>0}{}{\@error{unable to patch}}% replace the subsection number test with a test that always returns true
% use frame numbers instead of subsection slide numbers so that frames broken over slides get separate circles
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\c@subsectionslide}{\c@framenumber}{}{\@error{unable to patch}}
\patchcmd{\beamer@writeslidentry}{\c@subsectionslide}{\c@framenumber}{}{\@error{unable to patch}}
\makeatother
\else
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\fi

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Some text.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you comment out the first `\patchcmd`, everything just works fine. That suggest there is an error with the `\ifnum` (which I do not understand fully yet). But I think this shouldn’t even occur because LaTeX should ignore everything inside the `\iftargetBeamer`-block.

Please show me how I can successfully ignore the block when using the report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usual problem with skipping over conditionals. If the outer condition is false then Tex will be skipping over this

```
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\ifnum#2>0}{\ifnum2>0}{
```

so it will not expand `\patchcmd` in any way but it *will* see two `\ifnum` and add them to its internal `\if` matching and so will expect to see two `\fi` closing the inner ifs.

You could give it two `\fi` with `\@gobble{\fi\fi}` or similar but less obscure and more maintainable would be to put the patching into an external file that you input so it isn't seen when skipping.

Comment: The idea of my setup is as follows: If you write a document, you just include two files which contain declarations, usepackages etc. and you just chose with `\targetReporttrue` or similar what you want. Splitting it up to avoid such errors is a good idea though. Thanks very much for this idea, just using a different file, like `\input{beamer-cfg.tex}` after `\iftargetBeamer` would have been a solution too.

Comment: @Bambino in this specific case you could just not use `\ifnum` in the patch and rely on the fact that `#2` is only used in that one place, but I thought I'd answer the general question of why it errors and how to avoid.

Answer (score 5):

When skipping tokens in an unused branch of a conditional, TeX still keeps track of conditionals, so when `\iftargetBeamer` is false, the two `\ifnum` are paired with the only two `\fi` tokens you provide.

Just remove `\ifnum`, because it's not required for the patch.

```
\newif\iftargetReport
\newif\iftargetBeamer

\targetReporttrue
%\targetBeamertrue

\iftargetReport
  \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, ngerman]{scrreprt}
\else
  \iftargetBeamer
    \documentclass[ignorenonframetext, ngerman]{beamer}
  \else
    \typeout{no valid class defined, enter Ctrl-D (Linux) or Ctrl-Z (Windows)}
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endinput
  \fi
\fi

\iftargetBeamer
  \makeatletter
  \usepackage{etoolbox} 
  % replace the subsection number test with a test that always returns true
  \patchcmd{\slideentry}
    {#2>0}
    {2>0}
    {}{\@error{unable to patch}}
  % use frame numbers instead of subsection slide numbers so that frames 
  % broken over slides get separate circles
  \patchcmd{\slideentry}
    {\c@subsectionslide}
    {\c@framenumber}
    {}{\@error{unable to patch}}
  \patchcmd{\beamer@writeslidentry}
    {\c@subsectionslide}
    {\c@framenumber}
    {}{\@error{unable to patch}}
  \makeatother
\else
  \usepackage{beamerarticle}
\fi

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Some text.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, use `regexpatch`, so you can “hide” the conditional.

```
\newif\iftargetReport
\newif\iftargetBeamer

\targetReporttrue
%\targetBeamertrue

\iftargetReport
  \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, ngerman]{scrreprt}
\else
  \iftargetBeamer
    \documentclass[ignorenonframetext, ngerman]{beamer}
  \else
    \typeout{no valid class defined, enter Ctrl-D (Linux) or Ctrl-Z (Windows)}
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endinput
  \fi
\fi

\iftargetBeamer
  \makeatletter
  \usepackage{regexpatch}
  % replace the subsection number test with a test that always returns true
  \regexpatchcmd{\slideentry}
    {\c{ifnum}\cP.2>0}
    {\c{iftrue}}
    {}{\@error{unable to patch}}
  % use frame numbers instead of subsection slide numbers so that frames 
  % broken over slides get separate circles
  \xpatchcmd{\slideentry}
    {\c@subsectionslide}
    {\c@framenumber}
    {}{\@error{unable to patch}}
  \xpatchcmd{\beamer@writeslidentry}
    {\c@subsectionslide}
    {\c@framenumber}
    {}{\@error{unable to patch}}
  \makeatother
\else
  \usepackage{beamerarticle}
\fi

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Some text.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much to you too. For my specific problem I now use your solution. I accepted David Carlisle‘s answer though because I think he explains the overall problem better.
Could you direct me somewhere where I can read about how to use `\ifnum` and `\patchcmd` correctly? I don‘t understand what the patch really does yet and I think I could have answered the question myself if I would.

Comment: @Bambino It's not a problem of using `\ifnum` in the argument to `\patchcmd`, which is generally harmless; the issue is having `\ifnum` in code that is skipped over in a conditional. I added a different solution.