# beamer: Conflict Between 'allowframebreak' and 'Mini Frame Navigation'

Tags: beamer, glossaries

I use the `glossaries` for acronyms in my `beamer`. The list of acronyms became too large for one page, so instead of it growing out of bounds on one page, I used `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{ACRONYMS}` to allow it to break across pages. However, since using `allowframebreaks`, all the navigation points for acronyms are filled regardless of whether I am on that page or not. The same applies to bibliography when using `allowframebreaks` but I chose not to include any bibliography for simplicity. The problem is illustrated by the image below:

[image]

The `MWE` below recreates the problem:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym{a}{A}{A}
\newacronym{b}{B}{B}
\newacronym{c}{C}{C}
\newacronym{d}{D}{D}
\newacronym{e}{E}{E}
\newacronym{f}{F}{F}
\newacronym{g}{G}{G}
\newacronym{h}{H}{H}
\newacronym{i}{I}{I}
\newacronym{j}{J}{J}
\newacronym{k}{K}{K}
\newacronym{l}{L}{L}
\newacronym{m}{M}{M}
\newacronym{n}{N}{N}
\newacronym{o}{O}{O}
\newacronym{p}{P}{P}
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\makeglossaries
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=14mm,text margin right=14mm} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title{TITLE}

\author{John Doe\inst{1}}

\institute[\acrfull{b}]
{
  \inst{1}%
  {\acrfull{a}\\
  \acrfull{b}}}

\date{\today}

\subject{General relativity}

\newcommand{\nologo}{\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}}

\logo{%
    \makebox[\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}%
    }\hskip-.1cm%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section*{OUTLINE}

\begin{frame}{OUTLINE}

\tableofcontents

\end{frame}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\begin{frame}{INTRODUCTION}

INSERT INTRODUCTION. \acrshort{a}\acrshort{b}\acrshort{c}\acrshort{d}\acrshort{e}\acrshort{f}\acrshort{g}\acrshort{h}\acrshort{i}\acrshort{j}\acrshort{k}\acrshort{l}\acrshort{m}\acrshort{n}\acrshort{o}\acrshort{p}

\end{frame}

\section{CONCLUSION}

\begin{frame}{CONCLUSION}

INSERT CONCLUSION.

\end{frame}

\appendix

\section{BIBLIOGRAPHY}

\nologo{
\begin{frame}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}

INSERT BIBLIOGRAPHY

\end{frame}

\section{ACRONYMS}

% \begin{frame}{ACRONYMS}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{ACRONYMS}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,nonumberlist,title=ACRONYMS]

\end{frame}

\section{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}

\begin{frame}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}

\centering{
\includegraphics[height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
\hspace{30pt}
\includegraphics[height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
}

\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

I get that it might be designed to work like this since you probably are on the same page in the eyes of the `beamer` but I cannot help but wonder if it is possible to make it behave normally.

- Is it possible to have unfilled and filled navigation points when using `allowframebreaks`?

---

Edit (based on the answer by @Dr. Manuel Kuehner who also provided a superior `MWE`).

As @Dr. Manel Kuehner correctly asserted, this is not a problem limited to `glossaries` or `bibliography`. It is however a conflict between `allowframebreak` and mini frame navigation, which is why I changed the title of the question at his request.

Comment: Your question seems to be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132285/.

Comment: Please consider reporting this to beamer as a bug report.

Comment: BTW, you load graphicx twice.

Comment: Bug Tracker: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues

Comment: Update: I opened an issue for that, see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/761.

Comment: Thank you for your interest and also for following up on this, @Dr. Manuel Kuehner.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Reported the bug [here](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/761).

---

Not a solution but a better MWE.

- I cleaned your MWE.
- I also tested a normal `itemize` slide with the same result.
- So I assume that your question is not specific to the `glossaries` package.
- **Update:** Your question seems to be a duplicate of [Allowframebreaks causes beamer miniframes to misbehave](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132285/). However, I tried to use the provided solution but got an error message. Your question should/could have the title **beamer: Conflict Between 'allowframebreak' and 'Mini Frame Navigation'**.

---

```
% --- --- Start (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132285)
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66626/9115
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\ifnum#2>0}{\ifnum2>0}{}{\@error{unable to patch}}% replace the subsection number test with a test that always returns true
% use frame numbers instead of subsection slide numbers so that frames broken over slides get separate circles
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\c@subsectionslide}{\c@framenumber}{}{\@error{unable to patch}}
\patchcmd{\beamer@writeslidentry}{\c@subsectionslide}{\c@framenumber}{}{\@error{unable to patch}}
\makeatother
% --- --- End
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym{a}{A}{A}
\newacronym{b}{B}{B}
\newacronym{c}{C}{C}
\newacronym{d}{D}{D}
\newacronym{e}{E}{E}
\newacronym{f}{F}{F}
\newacronym{g}{G}{G}
\newacronym{h}{H}{H}
\newacronym{i}{I}{I}
\newacronym{j}{J}{J}
\newacronym{k}{K}{K}
\newacronym{l}{L}{L}
\newacronym{m}{M}{M}
\newacronym{n}{N}{N}
\newacronym{o}{O}{O}
\newacronym{p}{P}{P}
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\makeglossaries
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\begin{document}

\section{A}
% ---
\begin{frame}{INTRODUCTION}
INSERT INTRODUCTION. \acrshort{a}\acrshort{b}\acrshort{c}\acrshort{d}\acrshort{e}\acrshort{f}\acrshort{g}\acrshort{h}\acrshort{i}\acrshort{j}\acrshort{k}\acrshort{l}\acrshort{m}\acrshort{n}\acrshort{o}\acrshort{p}
\end{frame}

\section{B}
% ---
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{ACRONYMS}
\printglossary[
    type = \acronymtype,
    nonumberlist,
    title = ACRONYMS,
    ]
\end{frame}

\section{C}
% ---
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{TEST}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Dr. Manuel Kuehner. I agree that your `MWE` is far superior and less confusing than mine. I was not sure why this happened, so that is why I blamed it on the `glossary` and also the `bibliography`. I get the same error as you, and also a message saying "unable to patch" on the first page. Other than that, it seems to work quite well in filling the correct navigation points.

Comment: I updated the linked workaround. Hopefully removing the first `\patchcmd{\slideentry}` line will get things working again, though `\@error` should really be `\errmessage` in the other two lines.

Comment: @cyberSingularity Thanks a lot (+1).