# Remove a titlepage navigation dot in Beamer

Tags: beamer, titles, mini-frames

I would like to remove the `navigation dot` in Beamer that corresponds to the title page.
Here is a MWE. As you can see there is an empty dot for for the title page... how can I get rid of it?

**NOTE** I use the trick here [Beamer navigation circles without subsections?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/beamer-navigation-circles-without-subsections) to remove `subsection` navigation dots.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle] 


\title{Stackexchange is great}
\author{John}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{Motivation}

\begin{frame}{A sample slide}
hello
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A sample slide}
hello
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A sample slide}
world
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it seems to work:

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@beamer@writeslidentry\beamer@writeslidentry
\def\beamer@writeslidentry{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry\old@beamer@writeslidentry
\makeatother
```

I just removed the two `\addtocontents{nav}` invocations from `\beamer@writeslidentry`.