# Use bullets from mini-frames in sidebar outer theme

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I would like to reproduce the individual "bullets" you have under section names in the "mini-frames" outer theme under the subsection names in the navigation sidebar created in the "sidebar" outer theme.
From another question, [Multiple navigation dots in Beamer for one frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135964/multiple-navigation-dots-in-beamer-for-one-frame), I found out that the code that produces each mini-frame is from the function \slideentry.
What I have done so far is to modify the navigation command in the sidebar outertheme, \insertverticalnavigation (beamerbasenavigation.sty, lines 548-627) such that it no longer redefines \slideentry to be blank (line 572). This would give, for a example, a MWE as:

```
            \documentclass[compress]{beamer}
            \useoutertheme[right,width=50pt,height=25pt]{sidebar}
            \usetheme{Copenhagen}
            \makeatletter

            %Sidebar navigation code

            \def\insertverticalnavigation#1{%
              \vbox{%
                \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
                  \ifnum##5=\c@part%
                  \def\insertsectionhead{##2}%
                  \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
                  \def\insertpartheadnumber{##5}%
                  \hbox{{%
                    \usebeamerfont{section in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in sidebar}%
                      \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{%
                      \ifnum\c@section=##1%
                        \ifnum\c@subsection=0\relax%
                          {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}%
                        \else%
                          \ifx\beamer@nav@css\beamer@hidetext%
                            {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}%
                          \else%
                            {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}}%
                          \fi%
                        \fi%
                      \else
                        {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}}%
                      \fi}}}%
                  \beamer@currentsubsection=0\relax\fi}%

                %code commented out:
                %\def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
                %

                \def\beamer@subsectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
                  \ifnum##1=\c@part%
                  \def\insertpartheadnumber{##1}%
                  \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##2}%
                  \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##3}%
                  \def\insertsubsectionhead{##5}%
                   \beamer@tocifnothide{\ifnum\c@section=##2\ifnum\c@subsection=##3\beamer@nav@css\else\beamer@nav@oss\fi\else\beamer@nav@ooss\fi}%
                  {\hbox{{%
                    \usebeamerfont{subsection in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in sidebar}%
                      \hyperlink{Navigation##4}{%
                      \ifnum\c@section=##2%
                        \ifnum\c@subsection=##3%
                          \ifnum\c@subsubsection=0\relax%
                            {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar}}%
                          \else%
                            {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
                          \fi%
                        \else%
                          {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
                        \fi%
                      \else%
                        {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
                      \fi}}}%
                  }%
                  \fi}%
                \def\beamer@subsubsectionentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{%
                  \ifnum##1=\c@part%
                  \def\insertpartheadnumber{##1}%
                  \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##2}%
                  \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##3}%
                  \def\insertsubsubsectionheadnumber{##3}%
                  \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{##6}%
                  \beamer@tocifnothide{\ifnum\c@section=##2\ifnum\c@subsection=##3\beamer@nav@css\else\beamer@nav@oss\fi\else\beamer@nav@ooss\fi}%
                  {\hbox{{%
                    \usebeamerfont{subsubsection in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsubsection in sidebar}%
                      \hyperlink{Navigation##5}{%
                      \ifnum\c@section=##2%
                        \ifnum\c@subsection=##3%
                          \ifnum\c@subsubsection=##4%
                            {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar}}%
                          \else
                            {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}}%
                          \fi%
                        \else%
                          {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}}%
                        \fi%
                      \else%
                        {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}}%
                      \fi}}}%
                  }%
                  \fi}%
                %\beamer@currentsubsection=0\relax%
                \dohead%
              }%
            }


            \makeatother


            \begin{document}
            \section{Foo}
            \begin{frame}{Test1}
            content...
            \end{frame}
            \subsection{foo}
            \begin{frame}{Test2}
            content...
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}{Test3}
            content...
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}{Test4}
            content...
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}{Test5}
            content...
            \end{frame}\section{Goo}
            \begin{frame}{Test6}
            content...
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}{Test7}
            content...
            \end{frame}
            \section{goo}
            \begin{frame}{Test8}
            content...
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}{Test9}
            content...
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}{Test10}
            content...
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}{Test11}
            content...
            \end{frame}



            \end{document}
```

However with this the mini-frames don't format as they would with the standard mini-frame outer theme. See the picture below (I apologise for the bad formatting in the MWE, it is minimal).

[image: Second Frame from MWE]
As you can hopefully see from the picture of from the MWE, instead of aligning on a single row beneath each subsection each new mini-frame appears on a seperate line.
Does anyone know how one would get the mini-frames to generate properly or which code I could hack to attempt to get the correct behaviour?

Cheers.

Comment: For some reason, consecutives `\hbox`es will be put into different lines in the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

For miniframes, beamer does the following:

- Each frame (the circle/dot) is drawn in an `\hbox` of zero width. The position of the circle/dot is controlled by explicitly specifying the coordinate. (For example

  ```
  \hbox to0cm{\kern1cm O}
  \hbox to0cm{\kern2cm O}
  \hbox to0cm{\kern3cm O}
  ```

  )
- these frames (circles/dots) are put into another `\hbox`. By default, materials in an `\hbox` will be aligned horizontally.

---

On the other hand, there is a `\vbox` in the definition of `\insertverticalnavigation`, which forces all `\hbox`es be aligned vertically. Therefore the circles/dots do the lie on the same line.

To overcome, you have to compensate the line height, which seems to be exactly 5pt in this case. So, instead of `%\def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%`, you can put

```
\def\slideentry#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  %section number, subsection number, slide number, first/last frame, page number, part number
  \ifnum#6=\c@part\ifnum#2>0\ifnum#3>0%
    \ifbeamer@compress%
      \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
    \else%
      \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
      \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
    \fi%
  \kern-3pt% compensate line break
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
    \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
    \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
      \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
      \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt%
      \kern\beamer@tempdim
      \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim
      \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
          \usebeamerfont{mini frame}%
          \ifnum\c@section=#1%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=#2%
              \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
              \ifnum\c@subsectionslide=#3%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%\beamer@minislidehilight%
              \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}%\beamer@minisliderowhilight%
              \fi%
            \else%
              \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
              %\color{fg!50!bg}%
              \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
            \fi%
          \else%
            \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
            %\color{fg!50!bg}%
            \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
          \fi%
        }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
  }%
  \kern-2pt% compensate line break
  \fi\fi%
  \else%
  \fakeslideentry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \fi\ignorespaces
  }
```

This is the original definition of `\slideentry` except that two `\kern`s are added.

---

Playing code

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[right,width=50pt,height=25pt]{sidebar}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\makeatletter

\def\slideentry#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
    %section number, subsection number, slide number, first/last frame, page number, part number
    \ifnum#6=\c@part\ifnum#2>0\ifnum#3>0%
        \ifbeamer@compress%
            \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
        \else%
            \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
            \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
        \fi%
        \kern-3pt% compensate line break
        \hbox to 0pt{%
            \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
            \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
            \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
            \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
            \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
                \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
                \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
                \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
                \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt%
                \kern\beamer@tempdim
                \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim
                \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
                        \usebeamerfont{mini frame}%
                        \ifnum\c@section=#1%
                            \ifnum\c@subsection=#2%
                                \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
                                \ifnum\c@subsectionslide=#3%
                                    \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%\beamer@minislidehilight%
                                \else%
                                    \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}%\beamer@minisliderowhilight%
                                \fi%
                            \else%
                                \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
                                %\color{fg!50!bg}%
                                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
                            \fi%
                        \else%
                            \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
                            %\color{fg!50!bg}%
                            \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
                        \fi%
                    }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
        }%
        \kern-2pt% compensate line break
    \fi\fi%
    \else%
    \fakeslideentry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
    \fi\ignorespaces
}


%Sidebar navigation code

\def\insertverticalnavigation#1{%
  \vbox{%
    \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
      \ifnum##5=\c@part%
      \def\insertsectionhead{##2}%
      \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
      \def\insertpartheadnumber{##5}%
      \hbox{{%
        \usebeamerfont{section in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in sidebar}%
          \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{%
          \ifnum\c@section=##1%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=0\relax%
              {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}%
            \else%
              \ifx\beamer@nav@css\beamer@hidetext%
                {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}%
              \else%
                {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}}%
              \fi%
            \fi%
          \else
            {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}}%
          \fi}}}%
      \beamer@currentsubsection=0\relax\fi}%

    \def\beamer@subsectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
      \ifnum##1=\c@part%
      \def\insertpartheadnumber{##1}%
      \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##2}%
      \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##3}%
      \def\insertsubsectionhead{##5}%
       \beamer@tocifnothide{\ifnum\c@section=##2\ifnum\c@subsection=##3\beamer@nav@css\else\beamer@nav@oss\fi\else\beamer@nav@ooss\fi}%
      {\hbox{{%
        \usebeamerfont{subsection in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in sidebar}%
          \hyperlink{Navigation##4}{%
          \ifnum\c@section=##2%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=##3%
              \ifnum\c@subsubsection=0\relax%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar}}%
              \else%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
              \fi%
            \else%
              {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
            \fi%
          \else%
            {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
          \fi}}}%
      }%
      \fi}%
    \def\beamer@subsubsectionentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{%
      \ifnum##1=\c@part%
      \def\insertpartheadnumber{##1}%
      \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##2}%
      \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##3}%
      \def\insertsubsubsectionheadnumber{##3}%
      \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{##6}%
      \beamer@tocifnothide{\ifnum\c@section=##2\ifnum\c@subsection=##3\beamer@nav@css\else\beamer@nav@oss\fi\else\beamer@nav@ooss\fi}%
      {\hbox{{%
        \usebeamerfont{subsubsection in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsubsection in sidebar}%
          \hyperlink{Navigation##5}{%
          \ifnum\c@section=##2%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=##3%
              \ifnum\c@subsubsection=##4%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar}}%
              \else
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}}%
              \fi%
            \else%
              {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}}%
            \fi%
          \else%
            {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}}%
          \fi}}}%
      }%
      \fi}%
    %\beamer@currentsubsection=0\relax%
    \dohead%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
    \begin{frame}{Test1}
        content...
    \end{frame}

\subsection{foo}
    \begin{frame}{Test2}
        content...
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Test3}
        content...
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Test4}
        content...
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Test5}
        content...
    \end{frame}

\section{Goo}
    \begin{frame}{Test6}
        content...
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Test7}
        content...
    \end{frame}

\section{goo}
    \begin{frame}{Test8}
        content...
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Test9}
        content...
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Test10}
        content...
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Test11}
        content...
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a special beamer theme for this purpose, the `sidebarwithminiframes` outer theme. It can be found at http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer-contrib/themes/beamerauxtheme/themes/beamerouterthemesidebarwithminiframes.sty

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[right,width=50pt,height=25pt]{sidebarwithminiframes}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\begin{frame}{Test1}
content...
\end{frame}
\subsection{foo}
\begin{frame}{Test2}
content...
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Test3}
content...
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Test4}
content...
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Test5}
content...
\end{frame}\section{Goo}
\begin{frame}{Test6}
content...
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Test7}
content...
\end{frame}
\section{goo}
\begin{frame}{Test8}
content...
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Test9}
content...
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Test10}
content...
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Test11}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]