# Navigation circles shown for title page with patch for no-subsections

Tags: beamer, etoolbox, navigation

I'm trying to create a custom theme for beamer. However, when I tried to patch the navigation circles to be automatically included without subsections (using the solution of [Beamer navigation circles without subsections?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/beamer-navigation-circles-without-subsections)) the title page appears in the navigation circles.

I tried to remove all parts, but I can't find why it keeps adding the title page to the navigation bar. I tried my best to reduce the source to a MWE, and this code (below) produces the wrong circle. If you need more information I can provide the full or needed files.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\colorlet{firstColor}{gray!50}
\colorlet{secondColor}{red!80!black}

\beamer@compresstrue

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{}
{%
\leavevmode
\ifnum\insertframenumber>0\relax%remove it for the title page
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\the\paperwidth,ht=0.6cm]{section in head/foot}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox[fill=white](0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,0.6);
    \fill[secondColor] (0,0) rectangle(0.3,0.6);
    \fill[firstColor] (0.35,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,0.6);
    \node[anchor= west, white] at (0.3,0.3){\insertnavigation{0.85\paperwidth}};%
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\fi
}%


\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{}
{%
\vskip-1pt%skip after the begginning of the slide
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.2cm]{frametitle} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox[fill=white](0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,0.6);
  \fill[secondColor] (0,0) rectangle(0.3,1);
  \fill[firstColor] (0.35,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,0.6);
  \node[anchor=west, white,font=\large] at (0.4,0.25){\insertframetitle};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

% fix the title page navigation bar
\let\oldtitlepage\titlepage
\renewcommand{\titlepage}{%
  \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}%ensure that title page has 0 number
  \oldtitlepage%
}

% Patches beamer so that "subsections numbered 0" show their slide entries.
% Solution from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/beamer-navigation-circles-without-subsections
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\ifnum#2>0}{\ifnum2>0}{}{\@error{unable to patch}}% replace the subsection number test with a test that always returns true

\makeatother

\title{Test}
\subtitle{test}
\author{Doe}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{section name}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the title slide sits outside of any sections, so you could change the `\slideentry` conditions to require that the section number be strictly positive. i.e. change the `\patchcmd{\slideentry}` line to the following:

```
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\ifnum#2>0}{\ifnum#1>0}{}{\@error{unable to patch}}% require section number to be strictly positive
```

Would that be good enough?