# navigation bullets not displaying

Tags: beamer, navigation

I'm trying to use the Singapore theme with the navigation bullets on top but they do not appear unless I add a subsection within each section. Is there a way to avoid this?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\selectlanguage{spanish}

\usetheme{Singapore}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\title{Título}
\author{Autor}
\institute{Institute}
\date{\today} %


\begin{document}

\frame{\maketitle}
 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Contenido}
  \tableofcontents[]
 \end{frame}

\section{Without bullets}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contenido}
Contenido
\end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Objetivo}
  Objetivos 
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Bibiliografía}
 Bibliografía
 \end{frame}

  \section{With bullets}
\subsection{this will put the bullets}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contenido}
Contenido
\end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Objetivo}
  Objetivos 
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Bibiliografía}
 Bibliografía
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am working on a MAC with Lion. I am compiling with LaTEX and I use TexShop. I have saved my code as a latin-1 file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2078/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
    \@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\usetheme{Singapore}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\begin{document}

    \section{Without bullets}

        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Contenido}
            Contenido
        \end{frame}

        \begin{frame}
          \frametitle{Objetivo}
          Objetivos 
        \end{frame}

    \section{With bullets}

        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Contenido}
            Contenido
        \end{frame}

        \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Objetivo}
         Objetivos 
        \end{frame}

\end{document}
```