# Navigation bullets not displayed

Tags: beamer, presentations, bullets

this morning I woke up with a very wierd (at least in my opinion) in my presentation. I wrote all my presentation and I have a problem with last 3 slides because they do not show navigation bullets on the top, whereas all of the other slides do it. So, this is something different from what is answered in [navigation bullets not displaying](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195516/navigation-bullets-not-displaying) because my problem is only in the last 3 slides.

Here it is my MWE. It is my whole presentation in which I deleted all references to my work

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Beamer Presentation
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (10/11/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND THEMES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {

% The Beamer class comes with a number of default slide themes
% which change the colors and layouts of slides. Below this is a list
% of all the themes, uncomment each in turn to see what they look like.

%\usetheme{default}
%\usetheme{AnnArbor}
%\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Bergen}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}
%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
%\usetheme{Dresden}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\usetheme{Goettingen}
%\usetheme{Hannover}
%\usetheme[compress]{Ilmenau}
%\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
%\usetheme{Luebeck}
%\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme{Malmoe}
%\usetheme{Marburg}
%\usetheme{Montpellier}
%\usetheme{PaloAlto}
%\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
%\usetheme{Rochester}
%\usetheme{Singapore}
%\usetheme{Szeged}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}

% As well as themes, the Beamer class has a number of color themes
% for any slide theme. Uncomment each of these in turn to see how it
% changes the colors of your current slide theme.

%\usecolortheme{albatross}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\usecolortheme{beetle}
%\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usecolortheme{dolphin}
%\usecolortheme{dove}
%\usecolortheme{fly}
%\usecolortheme{lily}
%\usecolortheme{orchid}
%\usecolortheme{rose}
%\usecolortheme{seagull}
%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
%\usecolortheme{whale}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.25\textheight]{Logo.pdf}}

%\titlegraphic{\vspace{2cm}}

\title[Essays on Urban and Environmental Economics]{\textbf{Essays on Urban and Environmental Economics}} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author[Nicola De Vivo]{Nicola De Vivo} % Your name

\institute[IMT] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
15th December 2016 \\ % Your institution for the title page
}

%\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\date{
\begin{footnotesize}
%\textbf{IMT School for Advanced Studies Lucca}\\ \smallskip
%PhD Programme in Economics, Markets, Institutions - XXVII Cycle\\ \smallskip
%15th December 2016\\ \smallskip
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Advisor:} Bla Bla (Bla Bla)\\
\textbf{Co-Advisor:} Bla Bla (Bla Bla)
\end{flushleft}
\end{footnotesize}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\vspace{-0.01cm}
\begin{center}
\tikz [remember picture]
    \node at
        (current page.north)
        {\includegraphics[trim=0cm 6.5cm 0cm 1.5cm, width=.5\textwidth,height=.2\textheight]{Logo.pdf}};
\end{center}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}
%\end{document}

%\end{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}

\section[(Bla Bla]{Bla Bla}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Main research questions} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it

%\begin{center}
%\textbf{Main research questions}
%\end{center}

\begin{itemize}
\item "Bla Bla" \pause
\item "Bla Bla"
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{center}
\textit{"Bla Bla"}\\ Fazio and Modica (2012)
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Population distribution is not random, it follows a certain distribution\\
Three possible candidates:\\
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla
\end{enumerate}
Puzzle caused by two empirical regularities:\\
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla}
Formally established by Bla Bla (1949)\\
City sizes are said to satisfy a peculiar Bla Bla:\\

\begin{equation*}
Bla Bla
\end{equation*}

or, equivalently, the Bla Bla rule:

\begin{equation*}
Bla Bla
\end{equation*}

usually expressed in logarithmic terms:

\begin{equation*}
Bla Bla
\end{equation*}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla}
Formally established by Bla Bla (1931)\\
Growth rate of Bla Bla does not depend on the size of the Bla Bla (Bla Bla process)\\

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[trim=2cm 14cm 1.5cm 2.5cm, clip=true,width=8.0cm,height=4.5cm]{gibrat.pdf}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Why a puzzle?}
Bla Bla is a Pareto distribution with exponent equal to 1\\
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1999)
\item Bla Bla (1980)
\item Bla Bla (2005)
\end{itemize}
Bla Bla leads to a Log-Normal distribution\\
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (2004)
\item Bla Bla (1997)
\item Bla Bla (2003)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Trying to solve the puzzle}
Bla Bla process plus "something else"
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1999)
\item Bla Bla (2000)
\end{itemize}
Double Bla Bla distribution
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (2002)
\item Bla Bla (2010)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Our data}
Population of all Bla Bla Bla Bla on 3 censuses: 1991, 2001 e 2011\\
\begin{center}
\textbf{Why?}
\end{center}
\begin{itemize}
\item No unique definition of Bla Bla  \pause
\item All definitions given for statistical purposes \pause
\item Bla Bla do not cover all Bla Bla \pause
\item Proper Bla Bla definition based only on Bla Bla criteria
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{itemize}
\item "What is the actual Bla Bla of Bla Bla?"
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[trim=0.5cm 7.5cm 0.0cm 7.5cm, clip=true, width=8.0cm,height=5cm]{zipf_right_fit_1.pdf}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
Not Bla Bla
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{itemize}
\item "What is the actual Bla Bla of Bla Bla?"
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=1.5cm 7cm 0.5cm 7cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=4.5cm]{fit_90.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 9cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=4.55cm]{qqplot.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
Not Bla Bla
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{itemize}
\item "What is the actual Bla Bla of Bla Bla?"
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 9cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=4.5cm]{test_coda1.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 9cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=4.5cm]{test_coda2.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
Double Bla Bla!
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The model}
\begin{equation*}
dX=\mu Xdt+\sigma Xd\omega
\end{equation*}
Probability of creating new Bla Bla: $\lambda$ $dt$ in ($t$,$t+dt$)
\begin{center}
$\Downarrow$
\end{center}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(x)& =\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta} \left[x^{-\alpha-1}\exp\left\{\alpha\mu_{0}+\frac{\alpha^{2}\sigma_{0}^{2}}{2}\right\}
      \Phi\left(\frac{\ln(x)-\mu_{0}-\alpha\sigma_{0}^{2}}{\sigma_{0}}\right)\right. +\\
    & \quad \left.x^{\beta-1}\exp\left\{-\beta\mu_{0}+\frac{\beta^{2}\sigma_{0}^{2}}{2}\right\} \Phi^{c}\left(\frac{\ln(x)-\mu_{0}-\beta\sigma_{0}^{2}}{\sigma_{0}}\right)\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results of simulations}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[trim=3.75cm 10.0cm 4cm 10cm, clip=true, width=10.0cm,height=6.5cm]{prova_test_2.pdf}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A change in the paradigm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Does Bla Bla holds for Bla Bla?
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3.5cm 9.0cm 3.5cm 9.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{growth_size_mean_2001_1991_per.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=3.5cm 9.0cm 3.5cm 9.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{growth_size_mean_1961_1951.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusions}
\begin{itemize}
\item The way in which Bla Bla distribute across Bla Bla is still an open question \pause
\item Two widely recognized empirical regularities: Bla Bla and Bla Bla \pause
\item Double Bla Bla seems to be the most suitable for Bla Bla \pause
\item Model leading to it does not give good theoretical overlap \pause
\item Maybe a change in the Bla Bla is needed
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section[Bla Bla]{Bla Bla: Testing Bla Bla for Bla Bla}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1999): theoretical model leading to a Bla Bla process that follows Bla Bla driven by Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (2004): Bla Bla process characterized by two driving forces: Bla Bla process of local Bla Bla and perfect Bla Bla of Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\begin{center}
$\Downarrow$
\end{center}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla characteristics and Bla Bla concur in the Bla Bla of Bla Bla and Bla Bla
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{center}
Idiosyncratic reasons why Bla Bla decide to localize in a given Bla Bla or choose to move
\end{center}
\begin{center}
$\Downarrow$
\end{center}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (2001): Young Bla Bla prefer working in larger Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (2006): Different Bla Bla between old and young Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (1998): Bla Bla migrate in densely Bla Bla areas, while Bla Bla prefer Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (2015): \textsl{"as Bla Bla continues to Bla Bla, the Bla Bla of its Bla Bla has moved away from a Bla Bla and has been reshaped"}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Main research questions}
\begin{itemize}
\item What is the level of Bla Bla? \pause
\item What is Bla Bla for Bla Bla? \pause
\item Are there any differences between these two variables? \pause
\item Are there any differences if we differentiate for Bla Bla?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The data}
\begin{itemize}
\item Dataset provided by Bla Bla, Bla Bla Institute for Bla Bla Research
\item Annual observations for all Bla Bla, from 2001 to 2011
\item Total Bla Bla, divided by 5-year Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
Method proposed by Bla Bla (2013): estimate Bla Bla point as a parameter of a Bla Bla distribution, $h(\cdot)$, by means of Bla Bla estimation:\\

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{Bla Bla,Bla Bla,Bla Bla,q}{max}
& & \ln Bla Bla(P;Bla Bla,Bla Bla,Bla Bla,q),\\
& s.t. & & Bla Bla > \exp(Bla Bla)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Bla Bla coefficients in the Bla Bla rule estimated by a method proposed by Bla Bla (2011):

\begin{equation*}
\log(Bla Bla) = \log(Bla Bla)-q\log(Bla Bla)
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla coefficient vs. Bla Bla coefficient
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 5.5cm 0cm 5.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Bla Bla.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 5.5cm 0cm 5.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Bla Bla.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate vs. Bla Bla rate
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Figura_1.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Figura_4.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate vs. Bla Bla rate
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Figura_2.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Figura_5.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate vs. Bla Bla rate
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Figura_3.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Figura_6.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusions}
\begin{itemize}
\item First attempt to introduce different Bla Bla variables and Bla Bla in Bla Bla analysis \pause
\item Bla Bla much more concentrated than Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla is in operation for Bla Bla but not for Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla tend to agglomerate in Bla Bla, while Bla Bla show the opposite behavior
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section[Neutrality of Bla Bla]{How neutral is the choice of the Bla Bla in Bla Bla schemes? Evidence from the Bla Bla}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The Bla Bla}
\begin{itemize}
\item European Union Bla Bla Scheme
\item Main initiative of the European Union to reach Kyoto targets
\item Cap-and-trade scheme: emissions permits are exogenously capped and then allocated to participants
\item Three different periods: 2005-2007, 2008-2012, 2013-2020
\item Penalty for not complying
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The EU ETS}
\begin{itemize}
\item Covers all Bla Bla
\item Covers about Bla Bla
\item Accounts for Bla Bla
\item Unilaterally introduced $\Rightarrow$ Bla Bla
\item Three exemption criteria:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla criterion
\item Bla Bla criterion
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theoretical Bla Bla}
\begin{itemize}
\item Free Bla Bla can have distortionary effects
\item Absence of distortionary effects necessary to have effectiveness in Bla Bla scheme
\item Bla Bla (1960): in an ideal world, Bla Bla are independent
\item In real world Bla Bla schemes, free Bla Bla distorts Bla Bla outcomes:
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1995): in presence of Bla Bla costs
\item Bla Bla \textit{et al.} (1991): in presence of Bla Bla anomalies
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theoretical Bla Bla}
Evaluate causal relationship between Bla Bla and Bla Bla still challenging\\
Only two papers
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla (2013):
\begin{itemize}
\item Focus on Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla variable approach
\item Not significant Bla Bla effect \pause
\end{itemize}
\item Bla Bla and Bla Bla (2008):
\begin{itemize}
\item Spanish Bla Bla plants during Bla Bla 
\item Non Bla Bla in Bla Bla allocation rule
\item Not significant Bla Bla effect
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla trends
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=4cm 10cm 4cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Bla Bla.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 8cm 0cm 7.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Bla Bla.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate comparison
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{Bla Bla_rapporto_2008-2012.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{Bla Bla_rapporto_2013-2014.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate comparison
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{mean_esentati_2008_2012.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{mean_esentati_2013_2014.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla analysis}
\begin{itemize}
\item Focus on Bla Bla plants
\item Bla Bla approach
\item Estimate of the equation:
\begin{equation*}
log(Bla Bla_{it})=\beta Bla Bla_{s}\times Post2013_{t}+ X'\gamma + \tau_{t} \alpha_{i}+\varepsilon_{it}
\end{equation*}
\item Interest in $\beta$
\item Assignment to Bla Bla not random $\Rightarrow$ Bla Bla Bla Bla to Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla analysis}
Bla Bla (simple Bla Bla on Bla Bla)
\begin{table}
\centering
\tiny
\label{tab:att}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
Bla Bla &  & Bla Bla  & SE & t-test\\
\midrule
Change in Bla Bla  & Unmatched & -0.0437 & (0.0220) & -1.99\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0255 & (0.0292) & 0.87\\
Change in Bla Bla  & Unmatched & -0.0119 & (0.0240) & -0.49\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0496 & (0.0318) & 1.56\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & 0.0094 & (0.0309) & 0.30\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0754 & (0.0394) & 1.91*\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & -0.0232 & (0.0331) & -0.70\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0552 & (0.0407) & 1.36\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & 0.0419 & (0.0424) & 0.99\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.1365 & (0.0453) & 3.01***\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & 0.0667 & (0.0482) & 1.38\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.1908 & (0.0556) & 3.43***\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
Bla Bla with Bla Bla
\begin{table}
\centering
\tiny
\label{tab:diff_in_diff}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule
Bla Bla & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6)\\
\midrule
Bla Bla & 0.0133 & 0.0473* & 0.0445* & 0.0431* & 0.0686** & 0.0438\\
 & (0.0211) & (0.0270) & (0.0269) & (0.0228) & (0.0281) & (0.0277)\\
Bla Bla & 0.0762** & 0.151*** & 0.168*** & 0.136*** & 0.194*** & 0.169***\\
 & (0.0353) & (0.0453) & (0.0451) & (0.0383) & (0.0441) & (0.0437)\\
Bla Bla &  &  & 0.509*** &  &  & 0.567***\\
 &  &  & (0.0753) &  &  & (0.0957)\\
 \midrule
Bla Bla & No & Yes & Yes & No & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes\\
\midrule
N & 20125 & 19810 & 19810 & 20125 & 19810 & 19810\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
Effect for different Bla Bla criteria
\begin{table}
\centering
\tiny
\label{tab:diff_in_diff_criteria}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
log(verified emissions) & (1) & (2)\\
\midrule
Bla Bla & 0.0632*** & 0.0660** \\
 & (0.0239) & (0.0287)   \\
Bla Bla & 0.222*** & 0.227***\\
 & (0.0418) & (0.0476)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.00743 & -0.340***\\
 & (0.0304) & (0.0638)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.0324 & -0.697***\\
 & (0.0625) & (0.126)   \\
Bla Bla & 0.0619*** & 0.0577** \\
 & (0.0236) & (0.0266)   \\
Bla Bla & 0.150*** & 0.142***\\
 & (0.0423) & (0.0508)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.0642* & -0.00911   \\
 & (0.0349) & (0.0370)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.0443 & 0.0659   \\
 & (0.0603) & (0.0590)   \\
\midrule
Bla Bla & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & Yes\\
\midrule
N & 19810 & 19810\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusions}
\begin{itemize}
\item Empirical evaluation of the Bla Bla in Bla Bla schemes \pause
\item Based on data on Bla Bla \pause
\item Focus on Bla Bla establishments \pause
\item Our estimate suggests an increase in Bla Bla for Bla Bla that are exempted from Bla Bla \pause
\item Contradiction with Bla Bla prediction \pause
\item Bla Bla schemes efficiency could be improved
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Acknowledgement}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Advisor}: Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Co-Advisor}: Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Italian cities}: Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Ageing and Labor Market}: Bla Bla, Bla Bla and Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Allocation mechanism}: Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Now, let's go for a beer}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.75\textheight]{the_end_2.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am quite in a hurry, as on December 5th I am goind to defend.

Thank you very much

P.S.: I forgot to mention that last three slides are: conclusions of third paper, acknowledgement and greetings. They have nothing special, only text and a figure.

P.P.S.: I already tried to compile twice and even more but the result did not change, always no bullets displayed only in the last 3 slides

P.P.P.S: As I do not know how to add a MWE for this case, I am adding 2 of the three slides on which I see the problem, hoping it can help in understanding and solving the problem

[image]

As you can see, there is no highlighted bullet even if this slide belong to the last section.

Comment: Try to remove frames and replace text with some dummy text until you have a MWE. From your images, it seems something strange is going on, the alignment of the miniframes seems off.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. I tried it (after replacing all the images with `example-image.png`, as I obviously don't have your images) and the get the following https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKcw3.png which does show a bullet for the last slide.

Comment: What version of tex are you using? I tried with pdflatex from texlive 2016.

Comment: @samcarter I compiled with pdflatex using winedt 9.0

Comment: There are two problems on your title page 1) using `remember picture` alone will mess with the labels and caused the space in front of the miniframes, use `remember picture, overlay` instead. 2) giving the trim options without `clip` does nothing, so `trim=0cm 6.5cm 0cm 1.5cm, clip, width=.5\textwidth,height=.2\textheight`, but not sure, if this is the position you intended the logo to have.

Comment: @samcarter thanks for suggestions on the title page, I will use them and see what happens, even though I already used overlay and it caused logo overlap top bar. About last 3 slides, do you think it could be a problem of compiling or winedt version?

Comment: I think the minipages going off the margin might be a problem with the titlepage - and it breaking the navigation labels. The overlap with the top bar is expected, if you anchor your image at the very top of the page with `current page.north`. The version of windedt is probably  irrelevant, that is just a editor. What would be interesting is which tex distribution your are using, something like texlive or miktex.

Comment: @samcarter it is miktex 2.9

Comment: I tried to add overlay and to remove node at .... but it does not work. The logo in the title page goes on the right and bullets in the last 3 slides do not appear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49191/discussion-between-nicknock82-and-samcarter).

Answer (score 2):

This shows how to get rid of a lot of overfull boxes mentioned by op in an comment to @samcarter`s answer ...

With the following code I get only one overfull box that is left to you ...

The trick is to change your width from `0.5\textwidth` to `0.45\textwidth` (depending on the used images and their sizes).  Then images and space between them fits the total textwidth:

```
(0,45 + 0,45) * textwidth + spacelength <= textwidth
```

I changed the filenames to example-image-a (an image you can use in codes if you have installed package `MWE`) to get rid off the errors caused by using `_` in your filenames ...

Then I get with an current MiKTeX 2.9 0 errors, 5 warnings, 1 overfull box:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Beamer Presentation
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (10/11/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND THEMES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[draft]{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {

% The Beamer class comes with a number of default slide themes
% which change the colors and layouts of slides. Below this is a list
% of all the themes, uncomment each in turn to see what they look like.

%\usetheme{default}
%\usetheme{AnnArbor}
%\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Bergen}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}
%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
%\usetheme{Dresden}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\usetheme{Goettingen}
%\usetheme{Hannover}
%\usetheme[compress]{Ilmenau}
%\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
%\usetheme{Luebeck}
%\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme{Malmoe}
%\usetheme{Marburg}
%\usetheme{Montpellier}
%\usetheme{PaloAlto}
%\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
%\usetheme{Rochester}
%\usetheme{Singapore}
%\usetheme{Szeged}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}

% As well as themes, the Beamer class has a number of color themes
% for any slide theme. Uncomment each of these in turn to see how it
% changes the colors of your current slide theme.

%\usecolortheme{albatross}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\usecolortheme{beetle}
%\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usecolortheme{dolphin}
%\usecolortheme{dove}
%\usecolortheme{fly}
%\usecolortheme{lily}
%\usecolortheme{orchid}
%\usecolortheme{rose}
%\usecolortheme{seagull}
%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
%\usecolortheme{whale}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

%\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.25\textheight]{Logo.pdf}}

%\titlegraphic{\vspace{2cm}}

\title[Essays on Urban and Environmental Economics]{\textbf{Essays on Urban and Environmental Economics}} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author[Nicola De Vivo]{Nicola De Vivo} % Your name

\institute[IMT] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
15th December 2016 \\ % Your institution for the title page
}

%\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\date{
\begin{footnotesize}
%\textbf{IMT School for Advanced Studies Lucca}\\ \smallskip
%PhD Programme in Economics, Markets, Institutions - XXVII Cycle\\ \smallskip
%15th December 2016\\ \smallskip
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Advisor:} Bla Bla (Bla Bla)\\
\textbf{Co-Advisor:} Bla Bla (Bla Bla)
\end{flushleft}
\end{footnotesize}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\vspace{-0.01cm}
\begin{center}
\tikz [remember picture]
    \node at
        (current page.north)
        {\includegraphics[trim=0cm 6.5cm 0cm 1.5cm, width=.5\textwidth,height=.2\textheight]{Logo.pdf}};
\end{center}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}
%\end{document}

%\end{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}

\section[(Bla Bla]{Bla Bla}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Main research questions} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it

%\begin{center}
%\textbf{Main research questions}
%\end{center}

\begin{itemize}
\item "Bla Bla" \pause
\item "Bla Bla"
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{center}
\textit{"Bla Bla"}\\ Fazio and Modica (2012)
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Population distribution is not random, it follows a certain distribution\\
Three possible candidates:\\
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla
\end{enumerate}
Puzzle caused by two empirical regularities:\\
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla}
Formally established by Bla Bla (1949)\\
City sizes are said to satisfy a peculiar Bla Bla:\\

\begin{equation*}
Bla Bla
\end{equation*}

or, equivalently, the Bla Bla rule:

\begin{equation*}
Bla Bla
\end{equation*}

usually expressed in logarithmic terms:

\begin{equation*}
Bla Bla
\end{equation*}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla}
Formally established by Bla Bla (1931)\\
Growth rate of Bla Bla does not depend on the size of the Bla Bla (Bla Bla process)\\

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[trim=2cm 14cm 1.5cm 2.5cm, clip=true,width=8.0cm,height=4.5cm]{example-image-a}%{gibrat.pdf}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Why a puzzle?}
Bla Bla is a Pareto distribution with exponent equal to 1\\
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1999)
\item Bla Bla (1980)
\item Bla Bla (2005)
\end{itemize}
Bla Bla leads to a Log-Normal distribution\\
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (2004)
\item Bla Bla (1997)
\item Bla Bla (2003)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Trying to solve the puzzle}
Bla Bla process plus "something else"
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1999)
\item Bla Bla (2000)
\end{itemize}
Double Bla Bla distribution
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (2002)
\item Bla Bla (2010)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Our data}
Population of all Bla Bla Bla Bla on 3 censuses: 1991, 2001 e 2011\\
\begin{center}
\textbf{Why?}
\end{center}
\begin{itemize}
\item No unique definition of Bla Bla  \pause
\item All definitions given for statistical purposes \pause
\item Bla Bla do not cover all Bla Bla \pause
\item Proper Bla Bla definition based only on Bla Bla criteria
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{itemize}
\item "What is the actual Bla Bla of Bla Bla?"
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[trim=0.5cm 7.5cm 0.0cm 7.5cm, clip=true, width=8.0cm,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%{zipf_right_fit_1.pdf}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
Not Bla Bla
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{itemize}
\item "What is the actual Bla Bla of Bla Bla?"
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=1.5cm 7cm 0.5cm 7cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=4.5cm]{example-image-a}%{fit_90.pdf} 
&
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 9cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=4.55cm]{example-image-a}%{qqplot.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
Not Bla Bla
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{itemize}
\item "What is the actual Bla Bla of Bla Bla?"
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 9cm, clip=true,width=0.48\textwidth,height=4.5cm]{example-image-a}%{test_coda1.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 9cm, clip=true,width=0.48\textwidth,height=4.5cm]{example-image-a}%{test_coda2.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
Double Bla Bla!
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The model}
\begin{equation*}
dX=\mu Xdt+\sigma Xd\omega
\end{equation*}
Probability of creating new Bla Bla: $\lambda$ $dt$ in ($t$,$t+dt$)
\begin{center}
$\Downarrow$
\end{center}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(x)& =\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta} \left[x^{-\alpha-1}\exp\left\{\alpha\mu_{0}+\frac{\alpha^{2}\sigma_{0}^{2}}{2}\right\}
      \Phi\left(\frac{\ln(x)-\mu_{0}-\alpha\sigma_{0}^{2}}{\sigma_{0}}\right)\right. +\\
    & \quad \left.x^{\beta-1}\exp\left\{-\beta\mu_{0}+\frac{\beta^{2}\sigma_{0}^{2}}{2}\right\} \Phi^{c}\left(\frac{\ln(x)-\mu_{0}-\beta\sigma_{0}^{2}}{\sigma_{0}}\right)\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results of simulations}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[trim=3.75cm 10.0cm 4cm 10cm, clip=true, width=10.0cm,height=6.5cm]{example-image-a}%{prova_test_2.pdf}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A change in the paradigm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Does Bla Bla holds for Bla Bla?
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3.5cm 9.0cm 3.5cm 9.5cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%{growth_size_mean_2001_1991_per.pdf} 
&
\includegraphics[trim=3.5cm 9.0cm 3.5cm 9.5cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%{growth_size_mean_1961_1951.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusions}
\begin{itemize}
\item The way in which Bla Bla distribute across Bla Bla is still an open question \pause
\item Two widely recognized empirical regularities: Bla Bla and Bla Bla \pause
\item Double Bla Bla seems to be the most suitable for Bla Bla \pause
\item Model leading to it does not give good theoretical overlap \pause
\item Maybe a change in the Bla Bla is needed
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section[Bla Bla]{Bla Bla: Testing Bla Bla for Bla Bla}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1999): theoretical model leading to a Bla Bla process that follows Bla Bla driven by Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (2004): Bla Bla process characterized by two driving forces: Bla Bla process of local Bla Bla and perfect Bla Bla of Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\begin{center}
$\Downarrow$
\end{center}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla characteristics and Bla Bla concur in the Bla Bla of Bla Bla and Bla Bla
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{center}
Idiosyncratic reasons why Bla Bla decide to localize in a given Bla Bla or choose to move
\end{center}
\begin{center}
$\Downarrow$
\end{center}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (2001): Young Bla Bla prefer working in larger Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (2006): Different Bla Bla between old and young Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (1998): Bla Bla migrate in densely Bla Bla areas, while Bla Bla prefer Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (2015): \textsl{"as Bla Bla continues to Bla Bla, the Bla Bla of its Bla Bla has moved away from a Bla Bla and has been reshaped"}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Main research questions}
\begin{itemize}
\item What is the level of Bla Bla? \pause
\item What is Bla Bla for Bla Bla? \pause
\item Are there any differences between these two variables? \pause
\item Are there any differences if we differentiate for Bla Bla?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The data}
\begin{itemize}
\item Dataset provided by Bla Bla, Bla Bla Institute for Bla Bla Research
\item Annual observations for all Bla Bla, from 2001 to 2011
\item Total Bla Bla, divided by 5-year Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
Method proposed by Bla Bla (2013): estimate Bla Bla point as a parameter of a Bla Bla distribution, $h(\cdot)$, by means of Bla Bla estimation:\\

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{Bla Bla,Bla Bla,Bla Bla,q}{max}
& & \ln Bla Bla(P;Bla Bla,Bla Bla,Bla Bla,q),\\
& s.t. & & Bla Bla > \exp(Bla Bla)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Bla Bla coefficients in the Bla Bla rule estimated by a method proposed by Bla Bla (2011):

\begin{equation*}
\log(Bla Bla) = \log(Bla Bla)-q\log(Bla Bla)
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla coefficient vs. Bla Bla coefficient
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 5.5cm 0cm 5.5cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%{Bla Bla.pdf} 
&
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 5.5cm 0cm 5.5cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%{Bla Bla.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate vs. Bla Bla rate
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%{Figura_1.pdf} 
&
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%{Figura_4.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate vs. Bla Bla rate
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%{Figura_2.pdf} 
&
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%{Figura_5.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate vs. Bla Bla rate
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%{Figura_3.pdf} 
&
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%{Figura_6.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusions}
\begin{itemize}
\item First attempt to introduce different Bla Bla variables and Bla Bla in Bla Bla analysis \pause
\item Bla Bla much more concentrated than Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla is in operation for Bla Bla but not for Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla tend to agglomerate in Bla Bla, while Bla Bla show the opposite behavior
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section[Neutrality of Bla Bla]{How neutral is the choice of the Bla Bla in Bla Bla schemes? Evidence from the Bla Bla}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The Bla Bla}
\begin{itemize}
\item European Union Bla Bla Scheme
\item Main initiative of the European Union to reach Kyoto targets
\item Cap-and-trade scheme: emissions permits are exogenously capped and then allocated to participants
\item Three different periods: 2005-2007, 2008-2012, 2013-2020
\item Penalty for not complying
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The EU ETS}
\begin{itemize}
\item Covers all Bla Bla
\item Covers about Bla Bla
\item Accounts for Bla Bla
\item Unilaterally introduced $\Rightarrow$ Bla Bla
\item Three exemption criteria:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla criterion
\item Bla Bla criterion
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theoretical Bla Bla}
\begin{itemize}
\item Free Bla Bla can have distortionary effects
\item Absence of distortionary effects necessary to have effectiveness in Bla Bla scheme
\item Bla Bla (1960): in an ideal world, Bla Bla are independent
\item In real world Bla Bla schemes, free Bla Bla distorts Bla Bla outcomes:
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1995): in presence of Bla Bla costs
\item Bla Bla \textit{et al.} (1991): in presence of Bla Bla anomalies
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theoretical Bla Bla}
Evaluate causal relationship between Bla Bla and Bla Bla still challenging\\
Only two papers
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla (2013):
\begin{itemize}
\item Focus on Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla variable approach
\item Not significant Bla Bla effect \pause
\end{itemize}
\item Bla Bla and Bla Bla (2008):
\begin{itemize}
\item Spanish Bla Bla plants during Bla Bla 
\item Non Bla Bla in Bla Bla allocation rule
\item Not significant Bla Bla effect
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla trends
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=4cm 10cm 4cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%{example-image-a}%{Bla Bla.pdf} 
&
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 8cm 0cm 7.5cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}%{example-image-a}%{Bla Bla.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate comparison
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{example-image-a}%{"Bla Bla_rapporto_2008-2012.pdf"} 
&
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{example-image-a}%{"Bla Bla_rapporto_2013-2014.pdf"}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate comparison
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{example-image-a}%{mean_esentati_2008_2012.pdf} 
&
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{example-image-a}%{mean_esentati_2013_2014.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla analysis}
\begin{itemize}
\item Focus on Bla Bla plants
\item Bla Bla approach
\item Estimate of the equation:
\begin{equation*}
log(Bla Bla_{it})=\beta Bla Bla_{s}\times Post2013_{t}+ X'\gamma + \tau_{t} \alpha_{i}+\varepsilon_{it}
\end{equation*}
\item Interest in $\beta$
\item Assignment to Bla Bla not random $\Rightarrow$ Bla Bla Bla Bla to Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla analysis}
Bla Bla (simple Bla Bla on Bla Bla)
\begin{table}
\centering
\tiny
\label{tab:att}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
Bla Bla &  & Bla Bla  & SE & t-test\\
\midrule
Change in Bla Bla  & Unmatched & -0.0437 & (0.0220) & -1.99\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0255 & (0.0292) & 0.87\\
Change in Bla Bla  & Unmatched & -0.0119 & (0.0240) & -0.49\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0496 & (0.0318) & 1.56\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & 0.0094 & (0.0309) & 0.30\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0754 & (0.0394) & 1.91*\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & -0.0232 & (0.0331) & -0.70\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0552 & (0.0407) & 1.36\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & 0.0419 & (0.0424) & 0.99\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.1365 & (0.0453) & 3.01***\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & 0.0667 & (0.0482) & 1.38\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.1908 & (0.0556) & 3.43***\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
Bla Bla with Bla Bla
\begin{table}
\centering
\tiny
\label{tab:diff_in_diff}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule
Bla Bla & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6)\\
\midrule
Bla Bla & 0.0133 & 0.0473* & 0.0445* & 0.0431* & 0.0686** & 0.0438\\
 & (0.0211) & (0.0270) & (0.0269) & (0.0228) & (0.0281) & (0.0277)\\
Bla Bla & 0.0762** & 0.151*** & 0.168*** & 0.136*** & 0.194*** & 0.169***\\
 & (0.0353) & (0.0453) & (0.0451) & (0.0383) & (0.0441) & (0.0437)\\
Bla Bla &  &  & 0.509*** &  &  & 0.567***\\
 &  &  & (0.0753) &  &  & (0.0957)\\
 \midrule
Bla Bla & No & Yes & Yes & No & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes\\
\midrule
N & 20125 & 19810 & 19810 & 20125 & 19810 & 19810\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
Effect for different Bla Bla criteria
\begin{table}
\centering
\tiny
\label{tab:diff_in_diff_criteria}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
log(verified emissions) & (1) & (2)\\
\midrule
Bla Bla & 0.0632*** & 0.0660** \\
 & (0.0239) & (0.0287)   \\
Bla Bla & 0.222*** & 0.227***\\
 & (0.0418) & (0.0476)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.00743 & -0.340***\\
 & (0.0304) & (0.0638)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.0324 & -0.697***\\
 & (0.0625) & (0.126)   \\
Bla Bla & 0.0619*** & 0.0577** \\
 & (0.0236) & (0.0266)   \\
Bla Bla & 0.150*** & 0.142***\\
 & (0.0423) & (0.0508)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.0642* & -0.00911   \\
 & (0.0349) & (0.0370)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.0443 & 0.0659   \\
 & (0.0603) & (0.0590)   \\
\midrule
Bla Bla & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & Yes\\
\midrule
N & 19810 & 19810\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusions}
\begin{itemize}
\item Empirical evaluation of the Bla Bla in Bla Bla schemes \pause
\item Based on data on Bla Bla \pause
\item Focus on Bla Bla establishments \pause
\item Our estimate suggests an increase in Bla Bla for Bla Bla that are exempted from Bla Bla \pause
\item Contradiction with Bla Bla prediction \pause
\item Bla Bla schemes efficiency could be improved
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Acknowledgement}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Advisor}: Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Co-Advisor}: Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Italian cities}: Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Ageing and Labor Market}: Bla Bla, Bla Bla and Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Allocation mechanism}: Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Now, let's go for a beer}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.75\textheight]{example-image-a}%{the_end_2.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems on your title page 1) using `remember picture` alone will mess with the labels and caused the space in front of the miniframes, use `remember picture, overlay` instead. 2) giving the trim options without `clip` does nothing, so `trim=0cm 6.5cm 0cm 1.5cm, clip, width=.5\textwidth,height=.2\textheight`, but not sure, if this is the position you intended the logo to have.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}


\title[Essays on Urban and Environmental Economics]{\textbf{Essays on Urban and Environmental Economics}} %
\author[Nicola De Vivo]{Nicola De Vivo} % Your name
\institute[IMT]{
15th December 2016 \\ % Your institution for the title page
}

\date{
\begin{footnotesize}
%\textbf{IMT School for Advanced Studies Lucca}\\ \smallskip
%PhD Programme in Economics, Markets, Institutions - XXVII Cycle\\ \smallskip
%15th December 2016\\ \smallskip
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Advisor:} Bla Bla (Bla Bla)\\
\textbf{Co-Advisor:} Bla Bla (Bla Bla)
\end{flushleft}
\end{footnotesize}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\vspace{-0.01cm}
\begin{center}
\tikz [remember picture, overlay]
    \node at
        (current page.north)
        {\includegraphics[trim=0cm 6.5cm 0cm 1.5cm, clip, width=.5\textwidth,height=.2\textheight]{example-image}};
\end{center}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}
%\end{document}

%\end{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}

\section[(Bla Bla]{Bla Bla}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Main research questions} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it

%\begin{center}
%\textbf{Main research questions}
%\end{center}

\begin{itemize}
\item "Bla Bla" \pause
\item "Bla Bla"
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{center}
\textit{"Bla Bla"}\\ Fazio and Modica (2012)
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Population distribution is not random, it follows a certain distribution\\
Three possible candidates:\\
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla
\end{enumerate}
Puzzle caused by two empirical regularities:\\
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla}
Formally established by Bla Bla (1949)\\
City sizes are said to satisfy a peculiar Bla Bla:\\

\begin{equation*}
Bla Bla
\end{equation*}

or, equivalently, the Bla Bla rule:

\begin{equation*}
Bla Bla
\end{equation*}

usually expressed in logarithmic terms:

\begin{equation*}
Bla Bla
\end{equation*}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla}
Formally established by Bla Bla (1931)\\
Growth rate of Bla Bla does not depend on the size of the Bla Bla (Bla Bla process)\\

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[trim=2cm 14cm 1.5cm 2.5cm, clip=true,width=8.0cm,height=4.5cm]{example-image}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Why a puzzle?}
Bla Bla is a Pareto distribution with exponent equal to 1\\
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1999)
\item Bla Bla (1980)
\item Bla Bla (2005)
\end{itemize}
Bla Bla leads to a Log-Normal distribution\\
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (2004)
\item Bla Bla (1997)
\item Bla Bla (2003)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Trying to solve the puzzle}
Bla Bla process plus "something else"
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1999)
\item Bla Bla (2000)
\end{itemize}
Double Bla Bla distribution
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (2002)
\item Bla Bla (2010)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Our data}
Population of all Bla Bla Bla Bla on 3 censuses: 1991, 2001 e 2011\\
\begin{center}
\textbf{Why?}
\end{center}
\begin{itemize}
\item No unique definition of Bla Bla  \pause
\item All definitions given for statistical purposes \pause
\item Bla Bla do not cover all Bla Bla \pause
\item Proper Bla Bla definition based only on Bla Bla criteria
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{itemize}
\item "What is the actual Bla Bla of Bla Bla?"
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[trim=0.5cm 7.5cm 0.0cm 7.5cm, clip=true, width=8.0cm,height=5cm]{example-image}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
Not Bla Bla
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{itemize}
\item "What is the actual Bla Bla of Bla Bla?"
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=1.5cm 7cm 0.5cm 7cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=4.5cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 9cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=4.55cm]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
Not Bla Bla
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{itemize}
\item "What is the actual Bla Bla of Bla Bla?"
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 9cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=4.5cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 9cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=4.5cm]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
Double Bla Bla!
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The model}
\begin{equation*}
dX=\mu Xdt+\sigma Xd\omega
\end{equation*}
Probability of creating new Bla Bla: $\lambda$ $dt$ in ($t$,$t+dt$)
\begin{center}
$\Downarrow$
\end{center}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(x)& =\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta} \left[x^{-\alpha-1}\exp\left\{\alpha\mu_{0}+\frac{\alpha^{2}\sigma_{0}^{2}}{2}\right\}
      \Phi\left(\frac{\ln(x)-\mu_{0}-\alpha\sigma_{0}^{2}}{\sigma_{0}}\right)\right. +\\
    & \quad \left.x^{\beta-1}\exp\left\{-\beta\mu_{0}+\frac{\beta^{2}\sigma_{0}^{2}}{2}\right\} \Phi^{c}\left(\frac{\ln(x)-\mu_{0}-\beta\sigma_{0}^{2}}{\sigma_{0}}\right)\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results of simulations}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[trim=3.75cm 10.0cm 4cm 10cm, clip=true, width=10.0cm,height=6.5cm]{example-image}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A change in the paradigm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Does Bla Bla holds for Bla Bla?
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3.5cm 9.0cm 3.5cm 9.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[trim=3.5cm 9.0cm 3.5cm 9.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusions}
\begin{itemize}
\item The way in which Bla Bla distribute across Bla Bla is still an open question \pause
\item Two widely recognized empirical regularities: Bla Bla and Bla Bla \pause
\item Double Bla Bla seems to be the most suitable for Bla Bla \pause
\item Model leading to it does not give good theoretical overlap \pause
\item Maybe a change in the Bla Bla is needed
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section[Bla Bla]{Bla Bla: Testing Bla Bla for Bla Bla}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1999): theoretical model leading to a Bla Bla process that follows Bla Bla driven by Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (2004): Bla Bla process characterized by two driving forces: Bla Bla process of local Bla Bla and perfect Bla Bla of Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\begin{center}
$\Downarrow$
\end{center}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla characteristics and Bla Bla concur in the Bla Bla of Bla Bla and Bla Bla
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{center}
Idiosyncratic reasons why Bla Bla decide to localize in a given Bla Bla or choose to move
\end{center}
\begin{center}
$\Downarrow$
\end{center}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (2001): Young Bla Bla prefer working in larger Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (2006): Different Bla Bla between old and young Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (1998): Bla Bla migrate in densely Bla Bla areas, while Bla Bla prefer Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (2015): \textsl{"as Bla Bla continues to Bla Bla, the Bla Bla of its Bla Bla has moved away from a Bla Bla and has been reshaped"}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Main research questions}
\begin{itemize}
\item What is the level of Bla Bla? \pause
\item What is Bla Bla for Bla Bla? \pause
\item Are there any differences between these two variables? \pause
\item Are there any differences if we differentiate for Bla Bla?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The data}
\begin{itemize}
\item Dataset provided by Bla Bla, Bla Bla Institute for Bla Bla Research
\item Annual observations for all Bla Bla, from 2001 to 2011
\item Total Bla Bla, divided by 5-year Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
Method proposed by Bla Bla (2013): estimate Bla Bla point as a parameter of a Bla Bla distribution, $h(\cdot)$, by means of Bla Bla estimation:\\

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{Bla Bla,Bla Bla,Bla Bla,q}{max}
& & \ln Bla Bla(P;Bla Bla,Bla Bla,Bla Bla,q),\\
& s.t. & & Bla Bla > \exp(Bla Bla)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Bla Bla coefficients in the Bla Bla rule estimated by a method proposed by Bla Bla (2011):

\begin{equation*}
\log(Bla Bla) = \log(Bla Bla)-q\log(Bla Bla)
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla coefficient vs. Bla Bla coefficient
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 5.5cm 0cm 5.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 5.5cm 0cm 5.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate vs. Bla Bla rate
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate vs. Bla Bla rate
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate vs. Bla Bla rate
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusions}
\begin{itemize}
\item First attempt to introduce different Bla Bla variables and Bla Bla in Bla Bla analysis \pause
\item Bla Bla much more concentrated than Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla is in operation for Bla Bla but not for Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla tend to agglomerate in Bla Bla, while Bla Bla show the opposite behavior
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section[Neutrality of Bla Bla]{How neutral is the choice of the Bla Bla in Bla Bla schemes? Evidence from the Bla Bla}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The Bla Bla}
\begin{itemize}
\item European Union Bla Bla Scheme
\item Main initiative of the European Union to reach Kyoto targets
\item Cap-and-trade scheme: emissions permits are exogenously capped and then allocated to participants
\item Three different periods: 2005-2007, 2008-2012, 2013-2020
\item Penalty for not complying
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The EU ETS}
\begin{itemize}
\item Covers all Bla Bla
\item Covers about Bla Bla
\item Accounts for Bla Bla
\item Unilaterally introduced $\Rightarrow$ Bla Bla
\item Three exemption criteria:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla criterion
\item Bla Bla criterion
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theoretical Bla Bla}
\begin{itemize}
\item Free Bla Bla can have distortionary effects
\item Absence of distortionary effects necessary to have effectiveness in Bla Bla scheme
\item Bla Bla (1960): in an ideal world, Bla Bla are independent
\item In real world Bla Bla schemes, free Bla Bla distorts Bla Bla outcomes:
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1995): in presence of Bla Bla costs
\item Bla Bla \textit{et al.} (1991): in presence of Bla Bla anomalies
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theoretical Bla Bla}
Evaluate causal relationship between Bla Bla and Bla Bla still challenging\\
Only two papers
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla (2013):
\begin{itemize}
\item Focus on Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla variable approach
\item Not significant Bla Bla effect \pause
\end{itemize}
\item Bla Bla and Bla Bla (2008):
\begin{itemize}
\item Spanish Bla Bla plants during Bla Bla 
\item Non Bla Bla in Bla Bla allocation rule
\item Not significant Bla Bla effect
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla trends
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=4cm 10cm 4cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 8cm 0cm 7.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate comparison
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate comparison
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla analysis}
\begin{itemize}
\item Focus on Bla Bla plants
\item Bla Bla approach
\item Estimate of the equation:
\begin{equation*}
log(Bla Bla_{it})=\beta Bla Bla_{s}\times Post2013_{t}+ X'\gamma + \tau_{t} \alpha_{i}+\varepsilon_{it}
\end{equation*}
\item Interest in $\beta$
\item Assignment to Bla Bla not random $\Rightarrow$ Bla Bla Bla Bla to Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla analysis}
Bla Bla (simple Bla Bla on Bla Bla)
\begin{table}
\centering
\tiny
\label{tab:att}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
Bla Bla &  & Bla Bla  & SE & t-test\\
\midrule
Change in Bla Bla  & Unmatched & -0.0437 & (0.0220) & -1.99\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0255 & (0.0292) & 0.87\\
Change in Bla Bla  & Unmatched & -0.0119 & (0.0240) & -0.49\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0496 & (0.0318) & 1.56\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & 0.0094 & (0.0309) & 0.30\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0754 & (0.0394) & 1.91*\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & -0.0232 & (0.0331) & -0.70\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0552 & (0.0407) & 1.36\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & 0.0419 & (0.0424) & 0.99\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.1365 & (0.0453) & 3.01***\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & 0.0667 & (0.0482) & 1.38\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.1908 & (0.0556) & 3.43***\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
Bla Bla with Bla Bla
\begin{table}
\centering
\tiny
\label{tab:diff_in_diff}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule
Bla Bla & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6)\\
\midrule
Bla Bla & 0.0133 & 0.0473* & 0.0445* & 0.0431* & 0.0686** & 0.0438\\
 & (0.0211) & (0.0270) & (0.0269) & (0.0228) & (0.0281) & (0.0277)\\
Bla Bla & 0.0762** & 0.151*** & 0.168*** & 0.136*** & 0.194*** & 0.169***\\
 & (0.0353) & (0.0453) & (0.0451) & (0.0383) & (0.0441) & (0.0437)\\
Bla Bla &  &  & 0.509*** &  &  & 0.567***\\
 &  &  & (0.0753) &  &  & (0.0957)\\
 \midrule
Bla Bla & No & Yes & Yes & No & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes\\
\midrule
N & 20125 & 19810 & 19810 & 20125 & 19810 & 19810\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
Effect for different Bla Bla criteria
\begin{table}
\centering
\tiny
\label{tab:diff_in_diff_criteria}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
log(verified emissions) & (1) & (2)\\
\midrule
Bla Bla & 0.0632*** & 0.0660** \\
 & (0.0239) & (0.0287)   \\
Bla Bla & 0.222*** & 0.227***\\
 & (0.0418) & (0.0476)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.00743 & -0.340***\\
 & (0.0304) & (0.0638)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.0324 & -0.697***\\
 & (0.0625) & (0.126)   \\
Bla Bla & 0.0619*** & 0.0577** \\
 & (0.0236) & (0.0266)   \\
Bla Bla & 0.150*** & 0.142***\\
 & (0.0423) & (0.0508)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.0642* & -0.00911   \\
 & (0.0349) & (0.0370)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.0443 & 0.0659   \\
 & (0.0603) & (0.0590)   \\
\midrule
Bla Bla & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & Yes\\
\midrule
N & 19810 & 19810\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusions}
\begin{itemize}
\item Empirical evaluation of the Bla Bla in Bla Bla schemes \pause
\item Based on data on Bla Bla \pause
\item Focus on Bla Bla establishments \pause
\item Our estimate suggests an increase in Bla Bla for Bla Bla that are exempted from Bla Bla \pause
\item Contradiction with Bla Bla prediction \pause
\item Bla Bla schemes efficiency could be improved
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Acknowledgement}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Advisor}: Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Co-Advisor}: Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Italian cities}: Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Ageing and Labor Market}: Bla Bla, Bla Bla and Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Allocation mechanism}: Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Now, let's go for a beer}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.75\textheight]{example-image}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What I see in your image is that navigation top bar is even more centered than mine. Do you think is title page causing all this stuff? Thank you very much

Comment: I have a lot of Overfull \hbox warnings in compiling. Could those be a problem?

Comment: @nicknock82 Most of the overfull box warnings are caused by misusing two slashes to force a new line, while most of them are simply superfluous, the others should be replaced by an empty line. Can you show an image if you run the code from my answer?

Comment: I deleted all the two slashes. Rerunning the code gives the same overfull hbox when I insert the last table to the presentation.

Comment: the problem seems to rise when I add the slide where I put the last table. If I erase it, the problem goes on the following slide.

Comment: I run your code and it works. I modified mine following all of your suggestions (erase double slashes, reduced figure widths and added overlay) but it still does not work: full of overfull \hbox and last navigation dots not displayed.

Comment: the problem seem to rise when I overcome the slide number 40, do not understand why