# Overfull \hbox in presentation

Tags: beamer, warnings, presentations

Hy everyone,

in my presentation I have a further problem, maybe related to what I am asking [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341166/navigation-bullets-not-displayed): there are a lot of overfull \hbox, most of them are (16.41287pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active and a series of [].

The MWE is always the following

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Beamer Presentation
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (10/11/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND THEMES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {

% The Beamer class comes with a number of default slide themes
% which change the colors and layouts of slides. Below this is a list
% of all the themes, uncomment each in turn to see what they look like.

%\usetheme{default}
%\usetheme{AnnArbor}
%\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Bergen}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}
%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
%\usetheme{Dresden}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\usetheme{Goettingen}
%\usetheme{Hannover}
%\usetheme[compress]{Ilmenau}
%\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
%\usetheme{Luebeck}
%\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme{Malmoe}
%\usetheme{Marburg}
%\usetheme{Montpellier}
%\usetheme{PaloAlto}
%\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
%\usetheme{Rochester}
%\usetheme{Singapore}
%\usetheme{Szeged}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}

% As well as themes, the Beamer class has a number of color themes
% for any slide theme. Uncomment each of these in turn to see how it
% changes the colors of your current slide theme.

%\usecolortheme{albatross}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\usecolortheme{beetle}
%\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usecolortheme{dolphin}
%\usecolortheme{dove}
%\usecolortheme{fly}
%\usecolortheme{lily}
%\usecolortheme{orchid}
%\usecolortheme{rose}
%\usecolortheme{seagull}
%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
%\usecolortheme{whale}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.25\textheight]{Logo.pdf}}

%\titlegraphic{\vspace{2cm}}

\title[Essays on Urban and Environmental Economics]{\textbf{Essays on Urban and Environmental Economics}} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author[Nicola De Vivo]{Nicola De Vivo} % Your name

\institute[IMT] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
15th December 2016 \\ % Your institution for the title page
}

%\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\date{
\begin{footnotesize}
%\textbf{IMT School for Advanced Studies Lucca}\\ \smallskip
%PhD Programme in Economics, Markets, Institutions - XXVII Cycle\\ \smallskip
%15th December 2016\\ \smallskip
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Advisor:} Bla Bla (Bla Bla)\\
\textbf{Co-Advisor:} Bla Bla (Bla Bla)
\end{flushleft}
\end{footnotesize}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\vspace{-0.01cm}
\begin{center}
\tikz [remember picture,overlay]
    \node at
        (current page.north)
        {\includegraphics[trim=0cm 6.5cm 0cm 1.5cm, width=.5\textwidth,height=.2\textheight]{Logo.pdf}};
\end{center}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}
%\end{document}

%\end{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}

\section[(Bla Bla]{Bla Bla}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Main research questions} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it

%\begin{center}
%\textbf{Main research questions}
%\end{center}

\begin{itemize}
\item "Bla Bla" \pause
\item "Bla Bla"
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{center}
\textit{"Bla Bla"}\\ Fazio and Modica (2012)
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Population distribution is not random, it follows a certain distribution

Three possible candidates:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla
\end{enumerate}
Puzzle caused by two empirical regularities:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla}
Formally established by Bla Bla (1949)

City sizes are said to satisfy a peculiar Bla Bla:

\begin{equation*}
Bla Bla
\end{equation*}

or, equivalently, the Bla Bla rule:

\begin{equation*}
Bla Bla
\end{equation*}

usually expressed in logarithmic terms:

\begin{equation*}
Bla Bla
\end{equation*}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla}
Formally established by Bla Bla (1931)

Growth rate of Bla Bla does not depend on the size of the Bla Bla (Bla Bla process)

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[trim=2cm 14cm 1.5cm 2.5cm, clip=true,width=8.0cm,height=4.5cm]{gibrat.pdf}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Why a puzzle?}
Bla Bla is a Pareto distribution with exponent equal to 1
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1999)
\item Bla Bla (1980)
\item Bla Bla (2005)
\end{itemize}
Bla Bla leads to a Log-Normal distribution
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (2004)
\item Bla Bla (1997)
\item Bla Bla (2003)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Trying to solve the puzzle}
Bla Bla process plus "something else"
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1999)
\item Bla Bla (2000)
\end{itemize}
Double Bla Bla distribution
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (2002)
\item Bla Bla (2010)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Our data}
Population of all Bla Bla Bla Bla on 3 censuses: 1991, 2001 e 2011
\begin{center}
\textbf{Why?}
\end{center}
\begin{itemize}
\item No unique definition of Bla Bla  \pause
\item All definitions given for statistical purposes \pause
\item Bla Bla do not cover all Bla Bla \pause
\item Proper Bla Bla definition based only on Bla Bla criteria
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{itemize}
\item "What is the actual Bla Bla of Bla Bla?"
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[trim=0.5cm 7.5cm 0.0cm 7.5cm, clip=true, width=8.0cm,height=5cm]{zipf_right_fit_1.pdf}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
Not Bla Bla
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{itemize}
\item "What is the actual Bla Bla of Bla Bla?"
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=1.5cm 7cm 0.5cm 7cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=4.5cm]{fit_90.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 9cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=4.55cm]{qqplot.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
Not Bla Bla
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{itemize}
\item "What is the actual Bla Bla of Bla Bla?"
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 9cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=4.5cm]{test_coda1.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 9cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=4.5cm]{test_coda2.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
Double Bla Bla!
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The model}
\begin{equation*}
dX=\mu Xdt+\sigma Xd\omega
\end{equation*}
Probability of creating new Bla Bla: $\lambda$ $dt$ in ($t$,$t+dt$)
\begin{center}
$\Downarrow$
\end{center}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(x)& =\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta} \left[x^{-\alpha-1}\exp\left\{\alpha\mu_{0}+\frac{\alpha^{2}\sigma_{0}^{2}}{2}\right\}
      \Phi\left(\frac{\ln(x)-\mu_{0}-\alpha\sigma_{0}^{2}}{\sigma_{0}}\right)\right. +\\
    & \quad \left.x^{\beta-1}\exp\left\{-\beta\mu_{0}+\frac{\beta^{2}\sigma_{0}^{2}}{2}\right\} \Phi^{c}\left(\frac{\ln(x)-\mu_{0}-\beta\sigma_{0}^{2}}{\sigma_{0}}\right)\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results of simulations}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[trim=3.75cm 10.0cm 4cm 10cm, clip=true, width=10.0cm,height=6.5cm]{prova_test_2.pdf}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A change in the paradigm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Does Bla Bla holds for Bla Bla?
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3.5cm 9.0cm 3.5cm 9.5cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{growth_size_mean_2001_1991_per.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=3.5cm 9.0cm 3.5cm 9.5cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{growth_size_mean_1961_1951.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusions}
\begin{itemize}
\item The way in which Bla Bla distribute across Bla Bla is still an open question \pause
\item Two widely recognized empirical regularities: Bla Bla and Bla Bla \pause
\item Double Bla Bla seems to be the most suitable for Bla Bla \pause
\item Model leading to it does not give good theoretical overlap \pause
\item Maybe a change in the Bla Bla is needed
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section[Bla Bla]{Bla Bla: Testing Bla Bla for Bla Bla}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1999): theoretical model leading to a Bla Bla process that follows Bla Bla driven by Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (2004): Bla Bla process characterized by two driving forces: Bla Bla process of local Bla Bla and perfect Bla Bla of Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\begin{center}
$\Downarrow$
\end{center}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla characteristics and Bla Bla concur in the Bla Bla of Bla Bla and Bla Bla
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{center}
Idiosyncratic reasons why Bla Bla decide to localize in a given Bla Bla or choose to move
\end{center}
\begin{center}
$\Downarrow$
\end{center}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (2001): Young Bla Bla prefer working in larger Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (2006): Different Bla Bla between old and young Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (1998): Bla Bla migrate in densely Bla Bla areas, while Bla Bla prefer Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla (2015): \textsl{"as Bla Bla continues to Bla Bla, the Bla Bla of its Bla Bla has moved away from a Bla Bla and has been reshaped"}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Main research questions}
\begin{itemize}
\item What is the level of Bla Bla? \pause
\item What is Bla Bla for Bla Bla? \pause
\item Are there any differences between these two variables? \pause
\item Are there any differences if we differentiate for Bla Bla?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The data}
\begin{itemize}
\item Dataset provided by Bla Bla, Bla Bla Institute for Bla Bla Research
\item Annual observations for all Bla Bla, from 2001 to 2011
\item Total Bla Bla, divided by 5-year Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
Method proposed by Bla Bla (2013): estimate Bla Bla point as a parameter of a Bla Bla distribution, $h(\cdot)$, by means of Bla Bla estimation:\\

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{Bla Bla,Bla Bla,Bla Bla,q}{max}
& & \ln Bla Bla(P;Bla Bla,Bla Bla,Bla Bla,q),\\
& s.t. & & Bla Bla > \exp(Bla Bla)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Bla Bla coefficients in the Bla Bla rule estimated by a method proposed by Bla Bla (2011):

\begin{equation*}
\log(Bla Bla) = \log(Bla Bla)-q\log(Bla Bla)
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla coefficient vs. Bla Bla coefficient
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 5.5cm 0cm 5.5cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{Bla Bla.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 5.5cm 0cm 5.5cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{Bla Bla.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate vs. Bla Bla rate
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{Figura_1.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{Figura_4.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate vs. Bla Bla rate
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{Figura_2.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{Figura_5.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate vs. Bla Bla rate
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{Figura_3.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{Figura_6.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusions}
\begin{itemize}
\item First attempt to introduce different Bla Bla variables and Bla Bla in Bla Bla analysis \pause
\item Bla Bla much more concentrated than Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla is in operation for Bla Bla but not for Bla Bla \pause
\item Bla Bla tend to agglomerate in Bla Bla, while Bla Bla show the opposite behavior
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section[Neutrality of Bla Bla]{How neutral is the choice of the Bla Bla in Bla Bla schemes? Evidence from the Bla Bla}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The Bla Bla}
\begin{itemize}
\item European Union Bla Bla Scheme
\item Main initiative of the European Union to reach Kyoto targets
\item Cap-and-trade scheme: emissions permits are exogenously capped and then allocated to participants
\item Three different periods: 2005-2007, 2008-2012, 2013-2020
\item Penalty for not complying
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The EU ETS}
\begin{itemize}
\item Covers all Bla Bla
\item Covers about Bla Bla
\item Accounts for Bla Bla
\item Unilaterally introduced $\Rightarrow$ Bla Bla
\item Three exemption criteria:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla criterion
\item Bla Bla criterion
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theoretical Bla Bla}
\begin{itemize}
\item Free Bla Bla can have distortionary effects
\item Absence of distortionary effects necessary to have effectiveness in Bla Bla scheme
\item Bla Bla (1960): in an ideal world, Bla Bla are independent
\item In real world Bla Bla schemes, free Bla Bla distorts Bla Bla outcomes:
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla Bla (1995): in presence of Bla Bla costs
\item Bla Bla \textit{et al.} (1991): in presence of Bla Bla anomalies
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theoretical Bla Bla}
Evaluate causal relationship between Bla Bla and Bla Bla still challenging

Only two papers
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla Bla (2013):
\begin{itemize}
\item Focus on Bla Bla
\item Bla Bla variable approach
\item Not significant Bla Bla effect \pause
\end{itemize}
\item Bla Bla and Bla Bla (2008):
\begin{itemize}
\item Spanish Bla Bla plants during Bla Bla
\item Non Bla Bla in Bla Bla allocation rule
\item Not significant Bla Bla effect
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla trends
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=4cm 10cm 4cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{Bla Bla.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 8cm 0cm 7.5cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5cm]{Bla Bla.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate comparison
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{Bla Bla_rapporto_2008-2012.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{Bla Bla_rapporto_2013-2014.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{center}
Bla Bla rate comparison
\end{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{mean_esentati_2008_2012.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=3cm 9cm 3cm 10cm, clip=true,width=0.45\textwidth,height=5.0cm]{mean_esentati_2013_2014.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla analysis}
\begin{itemize}
\item Focus on Bla Bla plants
\item Bla Bla approach
\item Estimate of the equation:
\begin{equation*}
log(Bla Bla_{it})=\beta Bla Bla_{s}\times Post2013_{t}+ X'\gamma + \tau_{t} \alpha_{i}+\varepsilon_{it}
\end{equation*}
\item Interest in $\beta$
\item Assignment to Bla Bla not random $\Rightarrow$ Bla Bla Bla Bla to Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla analysis}
Bla Bla (simple Bla Bla on Bla Bla)
\begin{table}
\centering
\tiny
\label{tab:att}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
Bla Bla &  & Bla Bla  & SE & t-test\\
\midrule
Change in Bla Bla  & Unmatched & -0.0437 & (0.0220) & -1.99\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0255 & (0.0292) & 0.87\\
Change in Bla Bla  & Unmatched & -0.0119 & (0.0240) & -0.49\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0496 & (0.0318) & 1.56\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & 0.0094 & (0.0309) & 0.30\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0754 & (0.0394) & 1.91*\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & -0.0232 & (0.0331) & -0.70\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.0552 & (0.0407) & 1.36\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & 0.0419 & (0.0424) & 0.99\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.1365 & (0.0453) & 3.01***\\
Change in Bla Bla & Unmatched & 0.0667 & (0.0482) & 1.38\\
 & Bla Bla & 0.1908 & (0.0556) & 3.43***\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
Bla Bla with Bla Bla
\begin{table}
\centering
\tiny
\label{tab:diff_in_diff}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
Bla Bla & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (6)\\
\midrule
Bla Bla & 0.0133 & 0.0473* & 0.0445* & 0.0431* & 0.0438\\
 & (0.0211) & (0.0270) & (0.0269) & (0.0228) & (0.0277)\\
Bla Bla & 0.0762** & 0.151*** & 0.168*** & 0.136*** & 0.169***\\
 & (0.0353) & (0.0453) & (0.0451) & (0.0383) & (0.0437)\\
Bla Bla &  &  & 0.509*** & & 0.567***\\
 &  &  & (0.0753) & & (0.0957)\\
 \midrule
Bla Bla & No & Yes & Yes & No & Yes\\
Bla Bla & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & No & No & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & No & No & Yes & Yes\\
\midrule
N & 20125 & 19810 & 19810 & 20125 & 19810\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla Bla Analysis}
Effect for different Bla Bla criteria
\begin{table}
\centering
\tiny
\label{tab:diff_in_diff_criteria}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
log(verified emissions) & (1) & (2)\\
\midrule
Bla Bla & 0.0632*** & 0.0660** \\
 & (0.0239) & (0.0287)   \\
Bla Bla & 0.222*** & 0.227***\\
 & (0.0418) & (0.0476)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.00743 & -0.340***\\
 & (0.0304) & (0.0638)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.0324 & -0.697***\\
 & (0.0625) & (0.126)   \\
Bla Bla & 0.0619*** & 0.0577** \\
 & (0.0236) & (0.0266)   \\
Bla Bla & 0.150*** & 0.142***\\
 & (0.0423) & (0.0508)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.0642* & -0.00911   \\
 & (0.0349) & (0.0370)   \\
Bla Bla & -0.0443 & 0.0659   \\
 & (0.0603) & (0.0590)   \\
\midrule
Bla Bla & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & Yes & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & Yes\\
Bla Bla & No & Yes\\
\midrule
N & 19810 & 19810\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusions}
\begin{itemize}
\item Empirical evaluation of the Bla Bla in Bla Bla schemes \pause
\item Based on data on Bla Bla \pause
\item Focus on Bla Bla establishments \pause
\item Our estimate suggests an increase in Bla Bla for Bla Bla that are exempted from Bla Bla \pause
\item Contradiction with Bla Bla prediction \pause
\item Bla Bla schemes efficiency could be improved
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Acknowledgement}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Advisor}: Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Co-Advisor}: Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Italian cities}: Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Ageing and Labor Market}: Bla Bla, Bla Bla and Bla Bla
\item \textbf{Allocation mechanism}: Bla Bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Now, let's go for a beer}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.75\textheight]{the_end_2.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Can someone suggest me some solution?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know where the error is. Now I am working on debuggin my presentation one slide at time. Thank you very much

Comment: Even if you can't reduce the code, you could at least omit most of the commented lines. The lines at the top are good practice and may be required to attribute the code, but loads of the rest is just making it harder to see anything useful. You only need the active line for each theme option etc.

Answer (score 6):

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 5.5cm 0cm 5.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Bla Bla.pdf} &
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 5.5cm 0cm 5.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Bla Bla.pdf}
\end{tabular}
```

Produces an overfull box as the content of each column is .5\textwidth wide and has `\tabcolsep` padding either side so it `4\tabcolsep` too wide.

You don't need a `tabular` you could use

```
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 5.5cm 0cm 5.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Bla Bla.pdf}%
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 5.5cm 0cm 5.5cm, clip=true,width=0.5\textwidth,height=5cm]{Bla Bla.pdf}
```

which will put the two images side by side with no space, or use some smaller width such as .4\textwidth  depending on the intended effect.

Also never end a paragraph with `\\`
so

```
Three possible candidates:
\begin{enumerate}
```

not

```
Three possible candidates:\\
\begin{enumerate}
```

adding `\listfiles` to the preamble the log shows

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2015/01/05 3.36 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revi
sion 8a39122e1f63)
beamerbasercs.sty    2015/03/08 (rcs-revision 368aa9ba9d38)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2013/09/03 (rcs-revision 768f2d98ca64)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2013/03/10 (rcs-revision 47431932db0d)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
hyperref.sty    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2015/01/05  (rcs-revision b4b4bee242e2)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2013/09/03  (rcs-revision a55719c41d85)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2013/12/25  (rcs-revision f6bd5e3805da)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2013/06/07  (rcs-revision 60b9fe0f342f)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2014/02/20  (rcs-revision 4b8ceeeff434)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2015/01/05  (rcs-revision 431510bb5890)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 5cf6c5555a45)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2015/02/21  (rcs-revision d944b04ee2d5)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2015/03/08  (rcs-revision 7270298bbaae)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2014/06/30  (rcs-revision 580088513a67)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2014/09/10  (rcs-revision 393f6dcff371)
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2015/02/27  (rcs-revision 923f4bf87efa)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2016/06/28 v2.15d AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2015/03/04 v2.20.2
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2014/06/30  (rcs-revision 580088513a67)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerthemeBerlin.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthememiniframes.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemewhale.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemeorchid.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerinnerthemerectangles.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
booktabs.sty    2016/04/27 v1.618033 publication quality tables
   babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
   test.out
   test.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
ot1mathkerncmss.fd    2013/03/27 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OT1/mathk
erncmss.
 ***********
```

Comment: I deleted all the double slashes, I reduced all the widths and I used overlay in tikz specification but it still does not work, there is still a lot of overfull \hbox  as my number of slides goes over 40. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: Modified MWE, I ran on my pc and it gave me a big number of warning (overfull \hbox), especially when I compile the second time. Can you help me?

Comment: David, as I said before, the problem seems to emerge when the number of slides overcomes number 40, I cannot understand why

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to reduce the example, as problem emerge only when slides number is high.

Comment: Overfull \vbox (4.98605pt too high) detected at line 283
Overfull \hbox (8.33537pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 337--337
Overfull \vbox (3.46516pt too high) detected at line 346
Overfull \vbox (9.95651pt too high) detected at line 730

Comment: Could it be the miktex version? On my pc I obtained 72 bad boxes (on 67 slides, quite enough) and moreover, last 3 navigation bullets are not even displayed. I am using miktex 2.9

Comment: from the file as posted above? that's odd

Comment: Yes, the exact same file posted above.

Comment: the only overfull hbox I get is from \includegraphics[trim=3.75cm 10.0cm 4cm 10cm, clip=true, width=10.0cm,height=6.5cm]{prova_test_2.pdf}  which is 8pt too wide as specified.  Sorry can't do much more, Leave the comments here someone else will pass by and confirm if they get your results or mine, that would help narrow things down

Comment: @nicknock82 I get David's results. You are running it with the `demo` option, aren't you?

Comment: @cfr Yes, of course. Now, what I am trying is to run it on a different pc or miktex version, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @nicknock82 I will add `\listfiles` to my file and post the resulting list into my answer, then if you do the same you compare package versions